# C++ 'small' optimization behaving strangely

Tags: c++, optimization

I'm trying to optimize 'in the small' on a project of mine.

There's a series of array accesses that are individually tiny, but profiling has revealed that these array accesses are where the vast majority of my program is spending its time.  So, time to make things faster, since the program takes about an hour to run.

I've moved the following type of access:

```
const float theValOld1 = image(x, y, z);
const float theValOld2 = image(x, y+1, z);
const float theValOld3 = image(x, y-1, z);
const float theValOld4 = image(x-1, y, z);
```

etc, for 28 accesses around the current pixel.

where image thunks down to

```
float image(const int x, const int y, const int z) const {
     return data[z*xsize*ysize + y*xsize + x];
}
```

and I've replaced it with

```
const int yindex = y*xsize;
const int zindex = z*xsize*ysize;
const float* thePtr = &(data[z*xsize*ysize + y*xsize + x]);
const float theVal1 = *(thePtr);
const float theVal2 = *(thePtr + yindex);
const float theVal3 = *(thePtr - yindex);
const float theVal4 = *(thePtr - 1);
```

etc, for the same number of operations.

I would expect that, if the compiler were totally awesome, that this change would do nothing to the speed.  If the compiler is not awesome, then I'd say that the second version should be faster, if only because I'm avoiding the implict pointer addition that comes with the [] thunk, as well as removing the multiplications for the y and z indeces.

To make it even more lopsided, I've moved the z operations into their own section that only gets hit if zindex != 0, so effectively, the second version only has 9 accesses.  So by that metric, the second version should definitely be faster.

To measure performance, I'm using QueryPerformanceCounter.

What's odd to me is that the order of operations matters!

If I leave the operations as described and compare the timings (as well as the results, to make sure that the same value is calculated after optimization), then the older code takes about 45 ticks per pixel and the new code takes 10 ticks per pixel.  If I reverse the operations, then the old code takes about 14 ticks per pixel and the new code takes about 30 ticks per pixel (with lots of noise in there, these are averages over about 100 pixels).

Why should the order matter?  Is there caching or something happening?  The variables are all named different things, so I wouldn't think that would matter.  If there is some caching happening, is there any way I can take advantage of it from pixel to pixel?

Corollary: To compare speed, I'm supposing that the right way is to run the two versions independently of one another, and then compare the results from different runs.  I'd like to have the two comparisons next to each other make sense, but there's obviously something happening here that prevents that.  Is there a way to salvage this side-by-side run to get a reasonable speed comparison from a single run, so I can make sure that the results are identical as well (easily)?

EDIT: To clarify.

I have both new and old code in the same function, so I can make sure that the results are identical.

If I run old code and then new code, new code runs faster than old.
If I run new code and then old code, old code runs faster than new.

The z hit is required by the math, and the if statement cannot be removed, and is present in both.  For the new code, I've just moved more z-specific code into the z section, and the test code I'm using is 100% 2D.  When I move to 3D testing, then I'm sure I'll see more of the effect of branching.

Comment: Are you compiling this with all optimisations enabled? If not, your tests probably are not worth much.

Comment: O2, in release in visual studio 2008, default optimizations.  Are there any in particular I should be paying attention to?  Results are reported by cout's to the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If both the new and old versions run on the same data array, then yes, the last run will almost certainly get a speed bump due to caching. Even if the code is different, it'll be accessing data that was already touched by the previous version, so depending on data size, it *might* be in L1 cache, will probably be in L2 cache, and if a L3 cache exists, almost certainly in that. There'll probably also be some overlap in the code, meaning that the instruction cache will further boost performance of the second version.

A common way to benchmark is to run the algorithm once first, without timing it, simply to ensure that that's going to be cached, is cached, and then run it again a large number of times with timing enabled. (Don't trust a single execution, unless it takes at least a second or two. Otherwise small variations in system load, cache, OS interrupts or page faults can cause the measured time to vary). To eliminate the noise, measure the combined time taken for several runs of the algorithm, and obviously with no output in between. The fact that you're seeing spikes of 3x the usual time means that you're measuring at a *way* too fine-grained level. Which basically makes your timings useless.

> Why should the order matter? Is there caching or something happening? The variables are all named different things, so I wouldn't think that would matter. If there is some caching happening, is there any way I can take advantage of it from pixel to pixel?

The naming doesn't matter. When the code is compiled, variables are translated into memory addresses or register id's. But when you run through your image array, you're loading it all into CPU cache, so it can be read faster the next time you run through it.
And yes, you can and should take advantage of it.

The computer tries very hard to exploit spatial and temporal locality -- that is, if you access a memory address X at time T, it assumes that you're going to need address X+1 very soon (spatial locality), and that you'll probably also need X again, at time T+1 (temporal locality). It tries to speed up those cases in every way possible (primarily by caching), so you should try to exploit it.

> To make it even more lopsided, I've moved the z operations into their own section that only gets hit if zindex != 0, so effectively, the second version only has 9 accesses. So by that metric, the second version should definitely be faster.

I don't know where you placed that if statement, but if it's in a frequently evaluated block of code, the cost of the branch might hurt you more than you're saving. Branches *can* be expensive, and they inhibit the compiler's and CPU's ability to reorder and schedule instructions. So you may be better off without it. You should probably do this as a separate optimization that can be benchmarked in isolation.

I don't know which algorithm you're implementing, but I'm guessing you need to do this for every pixel?
If so, you should try to cache your lookups. Once you've got `image(x, y, z)`, that'll be the next pixel's `image(x+1, y, z)`, so cache it in the loop so the next pixel won't have to look it up from scratch. That would potentially allow you to reduce your 9 accesses in the X/Y plane down to three (use 3 cached values from the last iteration, 3 from the one before it, and 3 we just loaded in this iteration)

If you're updating the value of each pixel as a result of its neighbors values, a better approach may be to run the algorithm in a checkerboard pattern. Update every other pixel in the first iteration, using only values from their neighbors (which you're not updating), and then run a second pass where you update the pixels you read from before, based on the values of the pixels you updated before. This allows you to eliminate dependencies between neighboring pixels, so their evaluation can be pipelined and parallelized efficiently.

In the loop that performs all the lookups, unroll it a few times, and try to place all the memory reads at the top, and all the computations further down, to give the CPU a chance to overlap the two (since data reads are a lot slower, get them started, and while they're running, the CPU will try to find other instructions it can evaluate).

For any constant values, try to precompute them as much as possible. (rather than `z*xsize*ysize`, precompute `xsize*ysize`, and multiply z with the result of that.

Another thing that *may* help is to prefer local variables over globals or class members. You may gain something simply by, at the start of the function, making local copies of the class members you're going to need. The compiler can always optimize the extra variables out again if it wants to, but you make it clear that it shouldn't worry about underlying changes to the object state (which might otherwise force it to reload the members every time you access them)

And finally, study the generated assembly in detail. See where it's performing unnecessary store/loads, where operations are being repeated even though they could be cached, and where the ordering of instructions is inefficient, or where the compiler fails to inline as much as you'd hoped.

I honestly wouldn't expect your changes to the lookup function to have much effect though. An array access with the `operator[]` is easily convertible to the equivalent pointer arithmetic, and the compiler can optimize that pretty efficiently, as long as the offsets you're adding don't change.

Usually, the key to low-level optimizations is, somewhat ironically, *not* to look at individual lines of code, but at whole functions, and at loops. You need a certain amount of instructions in a block so you have something to work with, since a lot of optimizations deal with breaking dependencies between chains of instructions, reordering to hide instruction latency, and with caching individual values to avoid memory load/stores. That's almost impossible to do on individual array lookups, but there's almost certainly a lot gained if you consider a couple of pixels at a time.

Of course, as with almost all microoptimizations, there are no *always true* answers. Some of the above might be useful to you, or they might not.

If you tell us more about the access pattern (which pixels are you accessing, is there any required order, and are you just reading, or writing as well? If writing, when and where are the updated values used?)

If you give us a bit more information, we'll be able to offer much more specific (and likely to be effective) suggestions

Comment: The trick is, the image pixels are being accessed randomly.  So, checkerboarding or other kinds of overall patterns of access would be detrimental, because I'd almost certainly be loading more information than I'd need.

Answer (score 8):

You *may* (possibly) be running into some sort of readahead or cacheline boundary issue.  Generally speaking, when you load a single value and it isn't "hot" (in cache), the CPU will pull in a cache line (32, 64, or 128 bytes are pretty typical, depending on processor).  Subsequent reads to the same line will be much faster.

If you change the order of operations, you may just be seeing stalls due to how the lines are being loaded and evicted.

The best way to figure something like this out is to open "Disassembly" view and spend some quality time with your processor's reference manual.

If you're lucky, the changes that the code reordering causes will be obvious (the compiler may be generating extra instructions or branches).  Less lucky, it will be a stall somewhere in the processor -- during the decode pipeline or due to a memory fetch...

A good profiler that can count stalls and cache misses may help here too (AMD has [CodeAnalyst](http://developer.amd.com/CPU/CODEANALYST/Pages/default.aspx), for example).

If you're not under a time crunch, it's really worthwhile to dive into the disasm -- at the very least, you'll probably end up learning something you didn't know before about how your CPU, machine architecture, compiler, libraries, etc work.  (I almost always end up going "huh" when studying disasm.)

Answer (score 4):

When optimising, examining the data access pattern is essential.

for example:

assuming a width of 240

for a pixel at `<x,y,z> 10,10,0`

with original access pattern would give you:

```
a. data[0+ 10*240 + 10] -> data[2410]
b. data[0+ 11*240 + 10] -> data[2650]
c. data[0+  9*240 + 10] -> data[2170]
d. data[0+ 10*240 +  9] -> data[2409]
```

Notice the indices which are in arbitrary order.

Memory controller makes aligned accesses to the main memory to fill the cache lines.
If you order your operations so that accesses are to ascending memory addresses 
(e.g. `c,d,a,b` ) then the memory controller would be able to stream the data in to 
the cache lines.

Missing cache on read would be expensive as it has to search down the cache
hierarchy down to the main memory. Main memory access could be 100x slower than
cache. Minimising main memory access will improve the speed of your operation.

Comment: That's an interesting tip, I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 3):

> To make it even more lopsided, I've moved the z operations into their own section that only gets hit if zindex != 0, so effectively, the second version only has 9 accesses. So by that metric, the second version should definitely be faster.

Did you actually measure that?  Because I'd be pretty surprised if that were true.  An `if` statement in the inner loop of your program can add a surprising amount of overhead -- see [Is "IF" expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315306/is-if-expensive).  I'd be willing to bet that the overhead of the extra multiply is a lot less than the overhead of the branching, unless `z` happens to be zero 99% of the time.

> What's odd to me is that the order of operations matters!

The order of what operations?  It's not clear to me what you're reordering here.  Please give some more snippets of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please see my clarifications above.