# Why is x[i]=if faster than if... x[i]=

Tags: c, gcc, x86, x86-64, compiler-optimization

This has me baffled/intrigued, why is this code

[[see assembly]](https://godbolt.org/z/ofhqe44qj)

```
void maxArray(double* x, double* y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 65536; i++) {
        x[i] = ((y[i] > x[i]) ? y[i] : x[i]);
    }
}
```

...faster than this code?

[[see assembly]](https://godbolt.org/z/qd8c3oxcx)

```
void maxArray(double* x, double* y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 65536; i++) {
        if (y[i] > x[i]) x[i] = y[i];
    }
}
```

and for the record the resulting assembly in the first one is identical to the expanded version:

```
inline double fn(double a, double b) {
    if (a > b) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return b;
    }
}
void maxArray(double* x, double* y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 65536; i++) {
        x[i] = fn(y[i], x[i]);
    }
}
```

[[see assembly]](https://godbolt.org/z/6Yx6xc1vn)

I get the difference. The first one is setting `x[i]` to a condition, and the middle is conditionally setting `x[i]`. Both have conditions though, so both have branches? Is it because the expanded if statement for the latter is optimized into the vector assembly `max` command, and the former is, for some reason not recognized as a max function?

`gcc 10.3 x86_64 -Ofast -march=native`

Comment: You can see the exact compiler and flags if you click on any of the links.

Comment: Or you could include that information in the question so that clicking links is not necessary. Besides, the links did not load for me for some reason.

Comment: How many iterations - run over what time span? Was the  array content always the same? It must be at least 1 second to be useful.

Comment: Looks like this is critically dependent on the target CPU. You've used `-march=native`, which is whatever random CPU is used to host godbolt.org

Comment: Did you also consider `x[i] = std::max(x[i], y[i])` in your performance evaluation?

Comment: gcc x86_64 latest -Ofast -march=native

Comment: In the second variant, either the compiler didn't recognize the source code as an implementation of a maximum calculation, or it tried to more closely adhere to the source. In the first and third variant you have assignments in both branches, in the second variant you have an assignment in one branch only.

Comment: I suspect the compiler is reluctant to generate a store when you didn't ask for one.  Suppose for instance that the `x` array is in read-only memory, but that you know that its entries are all greater than the entries in `y`.  The second code, read strictly, ought to work (and do nothing), because the test is never true and `x[i]` is never assigned to.  But the first or third versions would crash.  As such, the compiler should not optimize #2 into the equivalent of #1, even if it knew #1 would be faster.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Yes, exactly, C compilers must not invent writes, for thread-safety if nothing else.  (So even checking for at least one element to be updated in an aligned vector wouldn't make it ok to store them all).  [Is it possible to use SIMD instruction for replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48285594), and see also this ICC bug: [Crash with icc: can the compiler invent writes where none existed in the abstract machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54524947)

Comment: @Alasdair: What CPU did you actually test this on?  Does it have AVX-512 like the servers Godbolt runs on? Were you using the same GCC (trunk) nightly build on your machine that you linked to on Godbolt (or did they make the same asm)?  (Although even without AVX-512, GCC makes similar asm using a `vmaskmovpd` masked store).  Also, how much faster, on what array size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be clear from the generated assembly code. In the first case you get:

```
# x[i] = ((y[i] > x[i]) ? y[i] : x[i])

vmovupd ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax
vmaxpd  ymm0, ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rdi+rax]
vmovupd YMMWORD PTR [rdi+rax], ymm0
```

While in the second case you get:

```
# if (y[i] > x[i]) x[i] = y[i];

vmovupd  ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax]
vcmppd   k1, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rdi+rax], 14
kortestb k1, k1
je       .L3
vmovupd  YMMWORD PTR [rdi+rax]{k1}, ymm0
```

As you can see in the first snippet, the compiler used the [`VMAXPD`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/maxpd) specialized instruction to compute the maximum of two double precision floating point values, without branching. In the second snippet though, there is a compare ([`VCMPPD`](https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/CMPPD.html)) followed by a test ([`KORTESTB`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/kortestw:kortestb:kortestq:kortestd)) and a branch ([`JE`](https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/Jcc.html)).

Comment: Interesting that the compiler didn't get that. Clang produces different code for the all three, with the last (function version) being the most optimized.

Comment: @Alasdair yeah, when you are down to this level of optimization it's quite hard to get the right code, even different versions of the same compiler could change the generated code.

Comment: @Alasdair A more correct name for optimizers would be "improvers". They don't find the optimal solution.

Comment: @klutt but thats... what optimization means. improvement. otherwise they'd be called optimalers :D

Comment: @Shark True, but many seem to think that it's "strange" as soon as the optimizer misses an opportunity to optimize ;)

Comment: it's likely related to one of the most upvoted questions on SO.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/4989451

Comment: @tstanisl no, that's unrelated, the problem there is the data, not the branch, which is always present, the code is always the same. Here instead the problem is that in one case the branch is there and in one case it is not, the code is different. Don't confuse the two!

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: It's hardly that simple!  Both ways are vectorized (with AVX512 if you use `-march=native` on Godbolt's server, could be totally different on the OP's actual machine); the branch only branches if *no* elements are to be stored from the whole vector.  Note the masked store to `[rdi+rax]{k1}`.  (Probably because the store can be slow with an all-zero mask, especially in a copy-on-write situation where it may need a microcode assist to not actually dirty the page.)

Comment: @Alasdair: it can't optimize to just `max` + vector store because it's not allowed to invent writes.  [Crash with icc: can the compiler invent writes where none existed in the abstract machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54524947) and [AVX-512 and Branching](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47481762)