# Julia short-circuiting

Tags: julia

Consider

```
function foo(x)
    x isa Bar || throw(ArgumentError("x is not a Int64..."))

    dosomething(x)
end
```

as opposed to a traditional

```
function foo(x)
    if !(x isa Bar) 
        throw(ArgumentError("x is not a Bar..."))
    end

    dosomething(x)
end
```

(functionally equivalent is `!(x isa Int64) && ...`) Poking around a few packages, it seems this sort of conditional evaluation is not popular -- at face value, it seems convenient, and I prefer it a bit stylistically.

Is there a consensus on this stylistically? I understand that using the Unicode \in is discouraged over the word "in" by at least the Blue style guide for the sake of readability/ compatibility -- is this something similar?

Is this less performant? At face value, it seems like it would take about the same number of operations. I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020855/short-circuiting-and-performance) as well, but the answers aren't very satisfying, even ignoring that it's now likely outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When asking yourself performance question like this it is usually good idea to peek into compiled code via `@code_lowered`, `@code_typed`, `@code_llvm`, `@code_native`. Each of those macros explains one step further in the compilation process.

Consider

```
function x5a(x)
    x < 5 && (x=5)
    x
end

function x5b(x)
    if x < 5
        x=5
    end
    x
end
```

Let's try `@code_lowered`

```
julia> @code_lowered x5a(3)
CodeInfo(
1 ─      x@_3 = x@_2
│   %2 = x@_3 < 5
└──      goto #3 if not %2
2 ─      x@_3 = 5
└──      goto #3
3 ┄      return x@_3
)

julia> @code_lowered x5b(3)
CodeInfo(
1 ─      x@_3 = x@_2
│   %2 = x@_3 < 5
└──      goto #3 if not %2
2 ─      x@_3 = 5
3 ┄      return x@_3
)
```

Almost identical - will it get simplified further in the compilation process? Let's see!

```
julia> @code_typed x5a(3)
CodeInfo(
1 ─ %1 = Base.slt_int(x@_2, 5)::Bool
└──      goto #3 if not %1
2 ─      nothing::Nothing
3 ┄ %4 = φ (#2 => 5, #1 => x@_2)::Int64
└──      return %4
) => Int64

julia> @code_typed x5b(3)
CodeInfo(
1 ─ %1 = Base.slt_int(x@_2, 5)::Bool
└──      goto #3 if not %1
2 ─      nothing::Nothing
3 ┄ %4 = φ (#2 => 5, #1 => x@_2)::Int64
└──      return %4
) => Int64
```

Both functions have identical lowered codes which means that they will result in an identical assembly code and hence execute identical sets of CPU instructions.

Regarding the style - it is not documented in official style guidelines so code readability is the criterion and like Bogumil said this style is quite popular.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience:

1. There should be no performance difference between `if` and short-circuting evaluation. The choice should be purely stylistic.
2. the style `cond || ...` and `cond && ...` is quite popular. Just if the expression following the `||` or `&&` is long so that it would not fit a single line then `if` is used.