# Irritating performance decrease by a simple additional branch

Tags: c, performance, x86, intel, compiler-optimization

In my project I have a function in which a code path should be conditionally skipped for performance reasons.
If the condition is true, I have an increase of up to 50 % as expected.
But if the condition is false, the performance for the normal path decreases 30 % in the worst case. Because the algorithm passes hundreds of loops, I can not understand why a simple additional `if` clause can have such big effect.

The function is part of libavfilter/vf_fillborders.c in project FFmpeg.org

```
static void mirror_borders16(FillBordersContext *s, AVFrame *frame)
{
    for (int p = 0; p < s->nb_planes; p++) {
        uint16_t *data = (uint16_t *)frame->data[p];
        int lz = frame->linesize[p] / sizeof(uint16_t);
        int width = s->planewidth[p];
        int left = s->borders[p].left;
        int right = s->borders[p].right;
        int height = s->planeheight[p];
        int height2 = height * lz;
        int top = s->borders[p].top;
        int top2 = top * lz;
        int bottom = height - s->borders[p].bottom;
        int bottom2 = bottom * lz;

        /* fill left and right borders from top to bottom border */
/********* Here is the additional code line: **********/
        if (left > 0 || right > 0) // in case skip for performance
/******************************************************/
            for (int y = top2; y < bottom2; y += lz) {
                for (int x = 0; x < left; x++)
                    data[y + x] = data[y + left * 2 - 1 - x];
                for (int x = 0; x < right; x++)
                    data[y + width - right + x] = data[y + width - right - 1 - x];
            }

        /* fill top and bottom borders */
        for (int y = 0; y < top2; y += lz)
            memcpy(data + y, data + (top2 * 2 - lz - y), width * sizeof(uint16_t));
        for (int y = 0; y < height2 - bottom2; y += lz)
            memcpy(data + (bottom2 + y),
                    data + (bottom2 - lz - y), width * sizeof(uint16_t));
    }
}
```

In a similar function I use the same trick to avoid the useless loop on `y` with `if (left > 0 || right < width)`
In this case the additional `if` clause only consumes ~0.5 % as expectable. Here the code:

```
static void smear_borders16(FillBordersContext *s, AVFrame *frame)
{
    for (int p = 0; p < s->nb_planes; p++) {
        uint16_t *data = (uint16_t *)frame->data[p];
        int lz = frame->linesize[p] / sizeof(uint16_t);
        int width = s->planewidth[p];
        int left = s->borders[p].left;
        int right = width - s->borders[p].right;
        int height = s->planeheight[p];
        int height2 = height * lz;
        int top = s->borders[p].top;
        int top2 = top * lz;
        int bottom = height - s->borders[p].bottom;
        int bottom2 = bottom * lz;

        /* fill left and right borders from top to bottom border */
        if (left > 0 || right < width) // in case skip for performance
            for (int y = top2; y < bottom2; y += lz) {
                for (int x = 0; x < left; x++)
                    data[y + x] = data[y + left];
                for (int x = right; x < width; x++)
                    data[y + x] = data[y + right - 1];
            }

        /* fill top and bottom borders */
        for (int y = 0; y < top2; y += lz)
            memcpy(data + y, data + top2, width * sizeof(uint16_t));
        for (int y = bottom2; y < height2; y += lz)
            memcpy(data + y, data + (bottom2 - lz), width * sizeof(uint16_t));
    }
}
```

My processor is Intel P8600. A hopefully MCVE can be found here: https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&u=forum.ubuntuusers.de%2Fpost%2F9064193 If you don't understand the translated German instructions, please comment.

Comment: Possibly could be cache misses, even though as far as I can see the memory regions touched under the `if` do not overlap the ones in the lower fill loop. You could profile both cases (with and without the left and right borders) with a given amount of loops, and check which function exactly grows in terms of consumed time - most likely `memcpy()` ?

Comment: Here's an interesting read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/315382/1849287

Comment: Aside: It appears that that `if` will save very little, unless, perhaps one of `left` or `right` is in fact zero most of the time. You could try `if (left + right > 0)` and see if that changes anything (I assume neither can be < 0).

Comment: @Rudolf @500
I understand, that a possible pipeline stall can cost ~20 CPU cycles. In my test the outer loop runs with top=0, bottom=600 and the inner with right=25, left=25, so 30,000 loops should run. I can not imagine, that additional 2 * ~20 cycles could harm much or that `if (left + right > 0)` could help significantly.
If I have right=0, left=0, top=25, bottom=575 I can save 550 outer loops with `if (left > 0 || right > 0)` which benefits as expected.

Comment: Please also see my supplement in the original question.

Comment: @Rudolf

What you mean by profiling?
I have run the function (with and without the `if` clause) 2048 times with right=25, left=25 and top=0, bottom=height (so `memcpy()` is not involved) with (it accumulates the times and calculates the average):

    START_TIMER
    s->fillborders(s, frame);
    STOP_TIMER(testcase)

Comment: @CosoCo - oh, i misunderstood, i though you were always having the bottom and top borders set but saw differences with and without the right and left borders. If the top and bottom borders are not set then of course yeah those memcpys are not getting involved, sorry.

Comment: Now I changed the offset of `right` to `int right = width - s->borders[p].right;` and used `if (left > 0 || right < width)` with
`                for (int x = right; x < width; x++)
                    data[y + x] = data[y + right * 2 - 1 - x];
`
Now the performance is again ok ... incredible.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError

After changing the offset of `right` as described in my last comment, I tried your trick with `if (left + width - right > 0)` and again the performance of the function decreased by 20 % ... really weird.

Comment: What is your processor? Can your provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Another interesting read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/1541563

Comment: @Hadi
My processor is Intel P8600.
A hopefully MCVE can be found here: https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/post/9064193/
If you don't understand the german instructions, please flag. Than I'll post a translation.

Comment: @Patri
I still thought, branch prediction is only a matter of the compiler, e.g. GCC, JIT ...
Is that wrong? Does a CPU collect history data for _each_ branch, and predicts different, depending on the data coming in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have investigated in disassembling the resulting machine code. Inserting `if (left > 0 || right > 0)` causes a significant change for the subsequent code by the compiler. It seems, the compiler optimizes suboptimal in the 2nd case, which could explain the 20 % performance decrease.

```
184         /* fill left and right borders from top to bottom border */
185         
186             for (int y = top2; y < bottom2; y += lz) {
   0x00000000002004ca <+138>:   cmp    %r14d,%esi
   0x00000000002004d1 <+145>:   jge    0x2005ad <mirror_borders16+365>
   0x00000000002004d7 <+151>:   movslq %ebx,%rax
   0x00000000002004da <+154>:   lea    -0x2(%rbp),%r15
   0x00000000002004de <+158>:   lea    -0x1(%r11),%r12d
   0x00000000002004e2 <+162>:   lea    (%rax,%rax,1),%r8
   0x00000000002004e6 <+166>:   movslq %esi,%rax
   0x000000000020050e <+206>:   mov    $0x1,%r12d
   0x0000000000200514 <+212>:   mov    %ebx,%r9d
   0x0000000000200517 <+215>:   mov    %rbx,0x30(%rsp)
   0x000000000020051c <+220>:   sub    %rax,%r15
   0x000000000020051f <+223>:   sub    %edx,%r12d
   0x0000000000200522 <+226>:   mov    %r14d,%ebx
   0x0000000000200525 <+229>:   nopl   (%rax)
   0x00000000002005a0 <+352>:   lea    (%r12,%rsi,1),%eax
   0x00000000002005a4 <+356>:   cmp    %eax,%ebx
   0x00000000002005a6 <+358>:   jg     0x200528 <mirror_borders16+232>
   0x00000000002005a8 <+360>:   mov    0x30(%rsp),%rbx

187                 for (int x = 0; x < left; x++)
   0x0000000000200528 <+232>:   test   %r11d,%r11d
   0x000000000020052b <+235>:   jle    0x20055f <mirror_borders16+287>
   0x000000000020052d <+237>:   movslq %esi,%r14
   0x0000000000200530 <+240>:   mov    %rdi,%rdx
   0x0000000000200533 <+243>:   mov    %ecx,(%rsp)
   0x0000000000200536 <+246>:   add    %r14,%r14
   0x0000000000200539 <+249>:   lea    0x0(%rbp,%r14,1),%rax
   0x000000000020053e <+254>:   add    %r13,%r14
   0x0000000000200541 <+257>:   nopl   0x0(%rax)
   0x0000000000200557 <+279>:   cmp    %rax,%r14
   0x000000000020055a <+282>:   jne    0x200548 <mirror_borders16+264>
   0x000000000020055c <+284>:   mov    (%rsp),%ecx

188                     data[y + x] = data[y + left * 2 - 1 - x];
   0x00000000002004e9 <+169>:   lea    (%r11,%r11,1),%edx
   0x00000000002004ed <+173>:   sub    $0x1,%ecx
   0x00000000002004f0 <+176>:   lea    0x0(%rbp,%rax,2),%rdi
   0x00000000002004f5 <+181>:   lea    -0x1(%r10),%eax
   0x00000000002004f9 <+185>:   add    %r12,%r12
   0x00000000002004fc <+188>:   mov    %r15,%r13
   0x00000000002004ff <+191>:   sub    %r10d,%ecx
   0x0000000000200502 <+194>:   add    %esi,%ecx
   0x0000000000200504 <+196>:   add    %rax,%rax
   0x0000000000200507 <+199>:   sub    %r12,%r13
   0x000000000020050a <+202>:   lea    -0x1(%rsi,%rdx,1),%esi
   0x0000000000200548 <+264>:   movzwl (%rax),%ecx
   0x000000000020054b <+267>:   sub    $0x2,%rax
   0x000000000020054f <+271>:   add    $0x2,%rdx
   0x0000000000200553 <+275>:   mov    %cx,-0x2(%rdx)

189                 for (int x = 0; x < right; x++)
   0x000000000020055f <+287>:   test   %r10d,%r10d
   0x0000000000200562 <+290>:   jle    0x200597 <mirror_borders16+343>
   0x0000000000200564 <+292>:   lea    0x1(%rcx),%edx
   0x0000000000200567 <+295>:   movslq %ecx,%r14
   0x000000000020056a <+298>:   mov    %ecx,(%rsp)
   0x000000000020056d <+301>:   add    %r14,%r14
   0x0000000000200570 <+304>:   movslq %edx,%rdx
   0x0000000000200573 <+307>:   lea    0x0(%rbp,%r14,1),%rax
   0x0000000000200578 <+312>:   add    %r15,%r14
   0x000000000020057b <+315>:   lea    0x0(%rbp,%rdx,2),%rdx
   0x000000000020058f <+335>:   cmp    %rax,%r14
   0x0000000000200592 <+338>:   jne    0x200580 <mirror_borders16+320>
   0x0000000000200594 <+340>:   mov    (%rsp),%ecx
   0x0000000000200597 <+343>:   add    %r9d,%esi
   0x000000000020059a <+346>:   add    %r9d,%ecx
   0x000000000020059d <+349>:   add    %r8,%rdi

190                     data[y + width - right + x] = data[y + width - right - 1 - x];
   0x0000000000200580 <+320>:   movzwl (%rax),%ecx
   0x0000000000200583 <+323>:   sub    $0x2,%rax
   0x0000000000200587 <+327>:   add    $0x2,%rdx
   0x000000000020058b <+331>:   mov    %cx,-0x2(%rdx)

191             }
```

With skipping useless looping:

```
184         /* fill left and right borders from top to bottom border */
185         if (left > 0 || right > 0) // in case skip for performance
   0x00000000002004f7 <+135>:   test   %r8d,%r8d
   0x00000000002004fe <+142>:   jg     0x200640 <mirror_borders16+464>
   0x0000000000200504 <+148>:   test   %ecx,%ecx
   0x0000000000200506 <+150>:   jg     0x200640 <mirror_borders16+464>

186             for (int y = top2; y < bottom2; y += lz) {
   0x0000000000200640 <+464>:   cmp    0x24(%rsp),%r15d
   0x0000000000200645 <+469>:   jge    0x20050c <mirror_borders16+156>
   0x000000000020064b <+475>:   mov    0x20(%rsp),%ebp
   0x0000000000200661 <+497>:   mov    %r15d,0x4c(%rsp)
   0x0000000000200666 <+502>:   sub    %ecx,%r9d
   0x0000000000200669 <+505>:   lea    -0x1(%rax,%r15,1),%esi
   0x000000000020066e <+510>:   mov    0x24(%rsp),%r15d
   0x0000000000200673 <+515>:   sub    %eax,%ebp
   0x0000000000200675 <+517>:   lea    (%r11,%rdx,2),%rdi
   0x0000000000200679 <+521>:   lea    -0x1(%r8),%edx
   0x000000000020067d <+525>:   mov    %ebp,%r10d
   0x0000000000200680 <+528>:   add    %r9d,%ebp
   0x0000000000200683 <+531>:   lea    -0x2(%r11),%r9
   0x0000000000200687 <+535>:   movslq %ebx,%r13
   0x000000000020068a <+538>:   add    %rdx,%rdx
   0x000000000020068d <+541>:   mov    %ebx,%r12d
   0x0000000000200690 <+544>:   mov    %r9,%r14
   0x0000000000200693 <+547>:   mov    $0x1,%r9d
   0x0000000000200699 <+553>:   add    %r13,%r13
   0x000000000020069c <+556>:   sub    %ecx,%r10d
   0x000000000020069f <+559>:   sub    %rdx,%r14
   0x00000000002006a2 <+562>:   sub    %eax,%r9d
   0x00000000002006a5 <+565>:   mov    %rbx,0x38(%rsp)
   0x00000000002006aa <+570>:   nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x000000000020072d <+701>:   lea    (%r9,%rsi,1),%eax
   0x0000000000200731 <+705>:   cmp    %eax,%r15d
   0x0000000000200734 <+708>:   jg     0x2006b0 <mirror_borders16+576>
   0x000000000020073a <+714>:   mov    0x38(%rsp),%rbx
   0x000000000020073f <+719>:   mov    0x4c(%rsp),%r15d
   0x0000000000200744 <+724>:   jmpq   0x20050c <mirror_borders16+156>
   0x0000000000200749 <+729>:   repz retq 
   0x000000000020074b:  nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

187                 for (int x = 0; x < left; x++)
   0x00000000002006b0 <+576>:   test   %r8d,%r8d
   0x00000000002006b3 <+579>:   jle    0x2006ec <mirror_borders16+636>
   0x00000000002006b5 <+581>:   movslq %esi,%rbx
   0x00000000002006b8 <+584>:   mov    %rdi,%rdx
   0x00000000002006bb <+587>:   mov    %ecx,0x8(%rsp)
   0x00000000002006bf <+591>:   add    %rbx,%rbx
   0x00000000002006c2 <+594>:   lea    (%r11,%rbx,1),%rax
   0x00000000002006c6 <+598>:   add    %r14,%rbx
   0x00000000002006c9 <+601>:   nopl   0x0(%rax)
   0x00000000002006df <+623>:   cmp    %rax,%rbx
   0x00000000002006e2 <+626>:   jne    0x2006d0 <mirror_borders16+608>
   0x00000000002006e4 <+628>:   mov    0x8(%rsp),%ecx
   0x00000000002006f0 <+640>:   mov    %esi,0x8(%rsp)
   0x00000000002006f4 <+644>:   cltq   
   0x00000000002006f6 <+646>:   lea    (%r11,%rax,2),%rdx
   0x00000000002006fa <+650>:   lea    0x0(%rbp,%rsi,1),%eax
   0x00000000002006fe <+654>:   cltq   
   0x0000000000200700 <+656>:   lea    (%r11,%rax,2),%rbx
   0x0000000000200704 <+660>:   xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000200706 <+662>:   nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

188                     data[y + x] = data[y + left * 2 - 1 - x];
   0x000000000020064f <+479>:   lea    (%r8,%r8,1),%eax
   0x0000000000200653 <+483>:   mov    0x18(%rsp),%r11
   0x0000000000200658 <+488>:   mov    $0x1,%r9d
   0x000000000020065e <+494>:   movslq %r15d,%rdx
   0x00000000002006d0 <+608>:   movzwl (%rax),%ecx
   0x00000000002006d3 <+611>:   sub    $0x2,%rax
   0x00000000002006d7 <+615>:   add    $0x2,%rdx
   0x00000000002006db <+619>:   mov    %cx,-0x2(%rdx)

189                 for (int x = 0; x < right; x++)
   0x00000000002006e8 <+632>:   test   %ecx,%ecx
   0x00000000002006ea <+634>:   jle    0x200727 <mirror_borders16+695>
   0x00000000002006ec <+636>:   lea    (%r10,%rsi,1),%eax
   0x000000000020071f <+687>:   cmp    %eax,%ecx
   0x0000000000200721 <+689>:   jg     0x200710 <mirror_borders16+672>
   0x0000000000200723 <+691>:   mov    0x8(%rsp),%esi
   0x0000000000200727 <+695>:   add    %r12d,%esi
   0x000000000020072a <+698>:   add    %r13,%rdi

190                     data[y + width - right + x] = data[y + width - right - 1 - x];
   0x0000000000200710 <+672>:   movzwl (%rdx),%esi
   0x0000000000200713 <+675>:   sub    $0x2,%rdx
   0x0000000000200717 <+679>:   mov    %si,(%rbx,%rax,2)
   0x000000000020071b <+683>:   add    $0x1,%rax

191             }
```