# How to to print this output in Python [top down (even)] [bottom up (odd)]

Tags: python

Trying to print this pattern of numbers
   want this output:(if a=10)

```
    2
    9
    4
    7
    6
    5
    8
    3
    10
    1
```

CODE::

```
a=10
for i in range(1,a+1):
  if(i%2==0):
    print(i)
  elif(a-i%2!=0):
    print(a-i)
```

Comment: Great start. Whats the problem? Are you getting any error code or message specifically?

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

As you starts form `2` I'd suggest the loop do the same, then depending if the value if odd or even, print the good things

```
a = 10
for i in range(2, a + 2):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(i)
    else:
        print(a - i + 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have no idea what this problem is about, but keeping to your approach
your style of code, you just need to flip every other value about, so:

```
a=10
for j in range(1,a+1):
  i = j + 1 if j % 2 else j - 1
  if(i%2==0):
    print(i)
  elif(a-i%2!=0):
    print(a-i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to run multiple iterators and run through them both:

```
a = 10
for i, j in zip(range(2, a + 2), range(a, 0, -1)):
    print(j if i % 2 else i)
```

Or you can create a single list with all the items:

```
a = 10
print([i for l in zip(range(2, a + 2, 2), range(a - 1, 0, -2)) for i in l])
```

The first `range` runs through the list forwards, and the second `range` runs backwards in each case.

Comment: I like the second one because there is no [`if`-branching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315306/is-if-expensive) to slow the code down (scales well if this was in a generator)