# identifier "__builtin_expect" is undefined (during ROS on win tutorial-talker example)

Tags: c++, ros

I'm trying to do the [first tutorial of ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/win_ros/hydro/Msvc%20SDK%20Projects) on Windows in Visual Studio 2015.

First I created a new WIN 32 Console application and copied the code from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber).
Then I configured the project as it is described in the guide. While Debugging there came up several errors:

- The identifier "`__builtin_expect`" is undefined in the files `service_client.h` and `TestTalker.cpp` (which is the name of my program).
- Cannot open source file "sys/time.h"

The SDK from [wiki.ros.org](http://wiki.ros.org/win_ros/hydro/Msvc%20SDK) runs, I tested it.
I have no idea what's wrong.
I hope someone can help me.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`__builtin_expect`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) is a [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) extension. It is not provided by Visual Studio.

Since it only provides a hint to the compiler to optimize for CPU branch-prediction, one could just replace all instances of `__builtin_expect(expr, c)` with `expr`.

<s>Or, in cases where it fits, use [__assume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b3fsfxw(VS.80).aspx) instead, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1440709/3919155).</s>

Comment: Those are different: `__builtin_expect` gives a hint to the compiler that an expression is most likely or more often true whereas `__assume` leads to UB when the hint is wrong. From [`__assume` doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b3fsfxw%28VS.80%29.aspx): "_Because the compiler generates code based on `__assume`, that code might not run correctly if the expression inside the `__assume` statement is false at run time._"

Comment: I'd suggest to just `#define __builtin_expect(x,y)` and let the optimization and branch prediction do the work. Related: [Optimizing a branch for a known more-common path](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35938249/5470596).

Comment: @YSC Double underscores in identifiers are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: Right. Then your answer is the best one can do. Go and `sed` the hell out of `service_client.h`!

Comment: Thank you all! The problem is that  there is no __builtin_expect in service_client.h, the errors appears in the following linie : private:   
  // This works around a problem with the OSX linker that causes the static variable declared by
  // ROS_ERROR to error with missing symbols when it's used directly in the templated call() method above
  // This for some reason only showed up in the rxtools package
  void deserializeFailed(const std::exception& e)
  {

    ROS_ERROR("Exception thrown while while deserializing service call: %s", e.what());
  }

Comment: the real definition is in console.h: #ifdef WIN32
#define ROS_LIKELY(x)       (x)
#define ROS_UNLIKELY(x)     (x)
#else
#define ROS_LIKELY(x)       __builtin_expect((x),1)
#define ROS_UNLIKELY(x)     __builtin_expect((x),0)
#endif

Comment: @chris_2091 Since this answer helped you, please accept it by clicking the check mark below the vote count.