# C++ Branch Prediction Hints

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, c++17

Consider the two equivalent functions

```
void foo( )
{
    if( unlikely_case )
        return;
    
    // foo code
}
```

```
void foo( )
{
    if( !unlikely_case )
    {
        // foo code
    }
}
```

Obviously, the compiler can't decide which case is more likely -- but I know ahead of time.

I feel that I should structure my code in the latter form since it is supports what I know of branch prediction.

The issue is this can get ugly

```
void foo( )
{
    if( !sanity_check[ 0 ] )
        return;
    if( !sanity_check[ 1 ] )
        return;
    if( !sanity_check[ 2 ] )
        return;

    // foo code
}
```

vs

```
void foo( )
{
    if( sanity_check[ 0 ] )
        if( sanity_check[ 1 ] )
            if( sanity_check[ 2 ] )
            {
                // foo code
            }
}
```

Is there a keyword I can use to let the compiler know which cases are more likely (probably compiler dependant)?
If not, are these sanity-check situations something the compiler takes into consideration when optimizing code for branch prediction?
Should I just get used to the pyramidal, latter code?

For the sake of the question, consider only the most popular compilers like MSVC, GCC, clang, etc.

Comment: Likely relevant: [How do the likely/unlikely macros in the Linux kernel work and what is their benefit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109710/how-do-the-likely-unlikely-macros-in-the-linux-kernel-work-and-what-is-their-ben)

Comment: The last one is equivalent to `if(check[0] && check[1] && check[2]) { /* foo code */ }` due to the shortcircuit rules. I would expect both forms to compile to the same code, at least when optimizations are enabled. This is orthogonal to the question of likelihood, however.

Comment: @dxiv I purposely separated them as usually sanity checks aren't things you can prepare within the `if()`. You must call a few functions and then decide.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yea that's GCC and is relevant to the question. That said, that question is old and I figured c++ added a keyword by now

Comment: Second answer to the question cited mentions C++20 `[[likely]]` and `[[unlikely]]` attributes.

Comment: So it's a C++ 20 feature, then... Disappointing but better late than never.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [likely/unlikely equivalent for MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440570/likely-unlikely-equivalent-for-msvc)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `__builtin_expect` built-in function, see more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346929/what-is-the-advantage-of-gccs-builtin-expect-in-if-else-statements).

Anyway, as a general rule, write first the most probable `if` branches, they will be executed before (this might not be true with `switch` blocks for example).

Comment: Could you comment on other compilers, like MSVC?