# Can likely/unlikely macros be used in user-space code?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, optimization, likely-unlikely

I came across these 2 macros in Linux kernel code. I know they are instructions to compiler (gcc) for optimizations in case of branching. My question is, can we use these macros in user space code? Will it give any optimization? Any example will be very helpful.

Comment: http://kerneltrap.org/node/4705

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109710/likely-unlikely-macros-in-the-linux-kernel

Comment: I checked these posts, but both again talks about kernel related stuff. I wanted to know whether same can be used in user code.

Comment: If you are programming for any reasonably powerful processor, you are unlikely to get any performance benefit. Modern dynamic branch predictors are quite good.

Comment: @Jay I think programmer should not assume power of processor. Dynamic branch detection would be easier if programmer explicitly provide the information.

Comment: @vinit, i create a random vector(from 0-100, branch is bigger than 0 or not) to measure "likely" brings performance gain compared branch prediction of CPU. Result shows it's similar time cost with or without likely.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes they can. [In the Linux kernel](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.31/include/linux/compiler.h#L138), they are defined as

```
#define likely(x)       __builtin_expect(!!(x), 1)
#define unlikely(x)     __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0)
```

The __builtin_expect macros are GCC specific macros that use the branch prediction; they tell the processor whether a condition is likely to be true, so that the processor can prefetch instructions on the correct "side" of the branch.

You should wrap the defines in an ifdef to ensure compilation on other compilers:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define likely(x)       __builtin_expect(!!(x), 1)
#define unlikely(x)     __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0)
#else
#define likely(x)       (x)
#define unlikely(x)     (x)
#endif
```

It will definitely give you optimizations if you use it for correct branch predictions.

Comment: In the #else part, shouldn't they evaluate to (x) and not empty?

Comment: which header file contains this definition in user include directories ?

Comment: @tonfa i dont want kernel's header file. I want file which is in /usr/include so that I can include it in my user space code.

Comment: They are only available in the kernels header file (or maybe in other projects). I suggest you create your own header file and add the definitions above. __builtin_expect is a gcc builtin and doesn't need an addition header file.

Comment: You should use !!(x) instead of just (x), to force the parameter to be converted to either 0 or 1.

Answer (score 12):

Take a look into [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/cpumemory.pdf) under "6.2.2 Optimizing Level 1 Instruction Cache Access" - there's a section about exactly this.

Comment: No problem. This is a very enlightening paper, even on a third read :)

Answer (score 4):

The likely() and unlikely() macros are pretty names defined in the kernel headers for something that *is* a real [gcc feature](http://kerneltrap.org/node/4705)