# How to communicate range information to C++ compiler?

Tags: c++, optimization, range, compile-time

Is there any way to indicate to the compiler that you know the value of a particular variable must be within a particular range at a certain point in the code, to assist the compiler with optimizing? I'm writing a library that makes it possible to know the range of some variables at compile time, and it would be nifty if it could somehow communicate this information to the compiler so that the compiler could use it for optimization. I'd like to add support for any compilers where it would work even if it couldn't be made to work for all of them (it sounds like the sort of thing that some compilers could have as an extension, but I haven't found any). I know I could write something like this:

```
if(x < COMPILE_TIME_MIN or x > COMPILE_TIME_MAX)
    return;
// compiler will assume for code below that x is in range COMPILE_TIME_MIN..COMPILE_TIME_MAX
```

But that's a runtime check. Maybe there's some trick to get the compiler to make an assumption about the range *without* such a check?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on what type of optimisation this would help with?

Comment: If you use templates, you can actually do compile time checking if all your information is known at compile time.

Comment: You are using the phrase "the compiler", but you never tell us which one.  Presumably you mean some version of g++ or Visual C++, but that isn't clear.  Optimization in general is not addressed by the Standard, so anything you could possibly do here is implementation-specific.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth:  The Visual C++ documentation, referenced below, contains one example involving a switch with an unreachable default case.

Comment: @JosephGarvin, do you mean the values are never outside this range or you want to make sure they stay outside the range? In the first case, you don't really need an `if`, since you are sure (for example by proof) that the values are always in that range. I'm saying because at least one of the answers assumes you mean the first case (the answer with `assert`)

Comment: @Shahbaz: I mean that the values are never outside the range, so yes for example if I had a proof. assert out of the box doesn't do the trick, because it gets disabled when NDEBUG is defined.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Generally the information can help the compiler remove dead code e.g. determining the default case of a switch can't be reached, or eliminating bounds checking, etc.

Comment: @JosephGarvin, so if by proof you know that the values **never** go outside of the range, why do you need an `if`? For example, if you have a 32bit unsigned int and you divide it by `1,000,000,000`, then checking to make sure it is in the range `[0,4]` is absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: @Shahbaz: I'd be using this trick inside functions that are likely to be inlined, where at the call site there may be ifs after calls to my function. Also the call sites are inside templated functions where the ifs may or may not be necessary depending on template parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any such "hint" would be compiler-specific.

As an example, Visual C++ allows you to provide such a hint using [the `__assume` intrinsic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b3fsfxw.aspx).

(Other compilers may also provide such intrinsics, but I am not familiar enough with other compilers to provide any further information.  Consult your compiler's documentation if you are interested.)

Comment: From my own googling, gcc 4.5 and above can pass this info along too with the same syntax using `#define __assume(cond) do { if (!(cond)) __builtin_unreachable(); } while (0)`

Comment: @DrewDormann Interesting.  I think it would be better to define a single macro `#define ASSUME_THIS_THING(x) ...` that expands to `__assume(x)` on Visual C++ and your snippet on gcc.  It's best not to define your own macro with a compiler-reserved name (like `__assume`).

Comment: Wow, that's awesome. James, care to merge Drew's info into your answer? Then I'll mark as accepted.

Comment: Also I think the do/while part is only needed in C. In C++ can just surround the if with braces.

Comment: @Joseph Garvin with only braces, your C++ compiler may make noise when the macro is followed by a semicolon.

Comment: @Shahbaz: I'd be using this trick inside functions that are likely to be inlined, where at the call site there may be ifs after calls to my function. Also those call sites are inside template functions where the ifs are sometimes and sometimes not necessary depending on the types passed as template parameters.

Answer (score 3):

It's not standard, but with gcc, there comes a command called `__builtin_expect`, with macros defined as `likely` and `unlikely` that serve your purpose. See [here](http://zeta-puppis.com/2006/02/09/likelyunlikely-gcc-extensions/) for example which talks about using them in kernel-space, but `__builtin_expect` is a gcc extension and could be used in user-space also (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1668013/912144)), even if `likely` and `unlikely` are not defined.

Comment: There's a typo in the above comment: it should be `__builtin_expect`. GCC only uses the expectation as a hint: it won't avoid cases where the expectation is not met.

Comment: @MattG, yeah I don't know how I had written `buildtin`!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any C++ compilation techniques that take advantage of this information, but I do know of various static analysis techniques that do; the common way to "tell" something to those tools would be via `assert`s, for instance:

```
assert(x > COMPILE_TIME_MIN);
assert(x < COMPILE_TIME_MAX);
```

**But** usually those tools would also be able to analyze things such as "if conditions" by themselves, so there's no special need to do so.

Additionally, if the range is really small, you can also represent it in a smaller-sized variable - e.g. using a short or char - and adding `COMPILE_TIME_MIN`. That can help such tools, though I don't know about the compilation itself.

And finally, as in all optimization approaches, I'd recommend first profiling your code to see if this could really be a bottleneck. Additionally, keep in mind that **compilers are designed for optimizing "normal" code** - hand-optimization could certainly help, just do it carefully.