# Is it possible to tell the branch predictor how likely it is to follow the branch?

Tags: c, gcc, x86, compiler-optimization, micro-optimization

Just to make it clear, I'm not going for any sort of portability here, so any solutions that will tie me to a certain box is fine.

Basically, I have an if statement that will 99% of the time evaluate to true, and am trying to eke out every last clock of performance, can I issue some sort of compiler command (using GCC 4.1.2 and the x86 ISA, if it matters) to tell the branch predictor that it should cache for that branch?

Comment: Compile with Profile Guided Optimization (-fprofile-generate, run on some test data, -fprofile-use).  Then gcc will know the stats for every branch, and be able to lay out the code optimally for the fast path.  But builtin_expect is still a good idea for places where it will help, in case code is compiled without PGO.  The Linux kernel has some good macros (e.g. likely() and unlikely()) for this, since it's hard to generate profile data for a kernel.

Comment: MS provides PGO as well -- http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2008/11/12/pogo.aspx.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Yes. http://kerneltrap.org/node/4705

> The `__builtin_expect` is a method that
>   gcc (versions >= 2.96) offer for
>   programmers to indicate branch
>   prediction information to the
>   compiler. The return value of
>   `__builtin_expect` is the first argument (which could only be an integer)
>   passed to it.

```
if (__builtin_expect (x, 0))
                foo ();

     [This] would indicate that we do not expect to call `foo', since we
     expect `x' to be zero.
```

Comment: In Microsoft environments, if statements are predicted to be always true. Some versions do have Profile Guided Optimisation.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109710/likely-unlikely-macros-in-the-linux-kernel-how-do-they-work-whats-their

Answer (score 82):

Yes, but it will have **no** effect. Exceptions are older (obsolete) architectures pre Netburst, and even then it doesn't do anything measurable.

There is an "branch hint" opcode Intel introduced with the Netburst architecture, and a default static branch prediction for cold jumps (backward predicted taken, forward predicted non taken) on some older architectures. GCC implements this with the `__builtin_expect (x, prediction)`, where prediction is typically 0 or 1.
The opcode emitted by the compiler is **ignored** on all newer processor architecures (>= Core 2). The small corner case where this actually does something is the case of a cold jump on the old Netburst architecture. Intel recommends now not to use the static branch hints, probably because they consider the increase of the code size more harmful than the possible marginal speed up.

Besides the useless branch hint for the predictor, `__builtin_expect` has its use, the compiler may reorder the code to improve cache usage or save memory.

There are multiple reasons it doesn't work as expected.

- The processor can predict small loops (n<64) perfectly.
- The processor can predict small repeating patterns (n~7) perfectly.
- The processor itself can estimate the probability of a branch during runtime better than the compiler/programmer during compile time.
- The **predictability** (= probability a branch will get predicted correctly) of a branch is far more important than the probability that the branch is taken. Unfortunately, this is highly architecture-dependent, and predicting the predictability of branch is notoriously hard.

Read more about the inner works of the branch prediction at Agner Fogs [manuals](http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf).
See also the gcc [mailing list](http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/gcc@gcc.gnu.org/msg20283.html).

Comment: Would be nice if you could quote / point to the exact portion where it says that the hint is ignored on newer architectures.

Comment: Chapter 3.12 "Static Prediction" in the link I gave.

Comment: When you say that smaller loops can be predicted perfectly, doesn't that mean that the loop has to complete once (possibly mispredicting the edges), then get all iterations to predict perfectly the next time the loop executes?

Answer (score 38):

Pentium 4 (aka Netburst microarchitecture) had branch-predictor hints as prefixes to the jcc instructions, but only P4 ever did anything with them. 
See http://ref.x86asm.net/geek32.html.  And
[Section 3.5 of Agner Fog's excellent asm opt guide](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_assembly.pdf), from  http://www.agner.org/optimize/.  He has a guide to optimizing in C++, too.

Earlier and later x86 CPUs silently ignore those prefix bytes.  [Are there any performance test results for usage of likely/unlikely hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607980/are-there-any-performance-test-results-for-usage-of-likely-unlikely-hints/7611307#7611307) mentions that PowerPC has some jump instructions which have a branch-prediction hint as part of the encoding.  It's a pretty rare architectural feature.  Statically predicting branches at compile time is very hard to do accurately, so it's usually better to leave it up to hardware to figure it out.

Not much is officially published about exactly how the branch predictors and branch-target-buffers in the most recent Intel and AMD CPUs behave.  The optimization manuals (easy to find on AMD's and Intel's web sites) give some advice, but don't document specific behaviour.  Some people have run tests to try to divine the implementation, e.g. how many BTB entries Core2 has...  Anyway, the idea of hinting the predictor explicitly has been abandoned (for now).

What is documented is for example that Core2 has a branch history buffer that can avoid mispredicting the loop-exit if the loop always runs a constant short number of iterations, < 8 or 16 IIRC.  But don't be too quick to unroll, because a loop that fits in 64bytes (or 19uops on Penryn) won't have instruction fetch bottlenecks because it replays from a buffer...  go read Agner Fog's pdfs, they're *excellent*.

See also [Why did Intel change the static branch prediction mechanism over these years?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822731/why-did-intel-change-the-static-branch-prediction-mechanism-over-these-years) : Intel since Sandybridge doesn't use static prediction at all, as far as we can tell from performance experiments that attempt to reverse-engineer what CPUs do.  (Many older CPUs have static prediction as a fallback when dynamic prediction misses.  The normal static prediction is forward branches are not-taken and backward branches are taken (because backwards branches are often loop branches).)

---

**The effect of `likely()`/`unlikely()` macros using GNU C's `__builtin_expect` (like Drakosha's answer mentions) does *not* directly insert BP hints into the asm**.  (It might possibly do so with `gcc -march=pentium4`, but not when compiling for anything else).

The actual effect is to lay out the code so the fast path has fewer taken branches, and perhaps fewer instructions total.  This will help branch prediction in cases where static prediction comes into play (e.g. dynamic predictors are cold, on CPUs which do fall back to static prediction instead of just letting branches alias each other in the predictor caches.)

See [What is the advantage of GCC's __builtin_expect in if else statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346929/what-is-the-advantage-of-gccs-builtin-expect-in-if-else-statements/31540623#31540623) for a specific example of code-gen.

Taken branches cost slightly more than not-taken branches, even when predicted perfectly.  When the CPU fetches code in chunks of 16 bytes to decode in parallel, a taken branch means that later instructions in that fetch block aren't part of the instruction stream to be executed.  It creates bubbles in the front-end which can become a bottleneck in high-throughput code (which doesn't stall in the back-end on cache-misses, and has high instruction-level parallelism).

**Jumping around between different blocks also potentially touches more cache-lines of code**, increasing L1i cache footprint and maybe causing more instruction-cache misses if it was cold.  (And potentially uop-cache footprint).  So that's another advantage to having the fast path be short and linear.

---

GCC's profile-guided optimization normally makes likely/unlikely macros unnecessary.  The compiler collects run-time data on which way each branch went for code-layout decisions, and to identify hot vs. cold blocks / functions.  (e.g. it will unroll loops in hot functions but not cold functions.)  See `-fprofile-generate` and `-fprofile-use` [in the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).  [How to use profile guided optimizations in g++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365980/how-to-use-profile-guided-optimizations-in-g)

Otherwise GCC has to guess using various heuristics, if you didn't use likely/unlikely macros and didn't use PGO.  `-fguess-branch-probability` is enabled by default at `-O1` and higher.

https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=gcc-82-pgo&num=1 has benchmark results for PGO vs. regular with gcc8.2 on a Xeon Scalable Server CPU.  (Skylake-AVX512).  Every benchmark got at least a small speedup, and some benefited by ~10%.  (Most of that is probably from loop unrolling in hot loops, but some of it is presumably from better branch layout and other effects.)

Comment: BTW, you probably don't need to use builtin_expect if you use profile-guided optimization.  PGO records which way each branch went, so when you compile with -fprofile-use, gcc knows which case is the common one for every branch.  It still doesn't hurt to use builtin_expect to tell it the fast path, in case your code will be built without PGO, though.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest rather than worry about branch prediction, profile the code and optimize the code to reduce the number of branches.  One example is loop unrolling and another using boolean programming techniques rather than using `if` statements.

Most processors love to prefetch statements.  Generally, a branch statement will generate a *fault* within the processor causing it to flush the prefetch queue.  This is where the biggest penalty is.  To reduce this penalty time, rewrite (and design) the code so that fewer branches are available.  Also, some processors can conditionally execute instructions without having to branch.

I've optimized a program from 1 hour of execution time to 2 minutes by using loop unrolling and large I/O buffers.  Branch prediction would not have offered much time savings in this instance.

Comment: What do you mean with "boolean programming techniques"?

Comment: @someonewithrpc that's combining multiples cases into a single one by using bitwise operations. a (stupid but still) example : replace a = b&1 ? 0 : 1; by a = b&1;

Comment: isn't it done by the compiler already?

Answer (score 1):

SUN C Studio has some pragmas defined for this case.

#pragma rarely_called ()

This works if one part of a conditional expression is a function call or starts with a function call.

But there is no way to tag a generic if/while statement

Answer (score -10):

No, because there's no assembly command to let the branch predictor know. Don't worry about it, the branch predictor is pretty smart.

Also, obligatory comment about premature optimization and how it's evil.

EDIT: Drakosha mentioned some macros for GCC. However, I believe this is a code optimization and actually has nothing to do with branch prediction.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Knuth. If this weren't a competition to see whose solution ran the absolute fastest, I would completely agree.

Comment: If you need every single cycle, why not just use inline assembly?

Comment: The full quote: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil.  Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.  **A good programmer will not be lulled into complacency by such reasoning**, he will be wise to look carefully at the critical code; but only after that code has been identified." (emphasis mine)

Comment: The branch predictor has a static rule when it knows nothing about a branch: take backwards branches, don't take forwards branches.  If you think about how a for loop works you'll understand why that makes sense, since you jump back to the top of the loop many more times than you don't.  So what the GCC macro is controlling is how GCC lays out the opcodes in memory, so that the forward / backward branch prediction rule is most effective.

Comment: This is plain wrong, there is actually an assembly command for letting the branch predictor know. It is ignored on all architectures but the Netburst, though.

Comment: @don.neufeld: The static rule you mentioned exists only on older architectures, for Core2 and up the direction of a cold jump is pseudo-random, because it depends on an overwritten entry in the history table.

Answer (score -11):

This sounds to me like overkill - this type of optimization will save tiny amounts of time. For example, using a more modern version of gcc will have a much greater influence on optimizations. Also, try enabling and disabling all the different optimization flags; they don't all improve performance.

Basically, it seems super unlikely this will make any significant difference compared to many other fruitful paths.

EDIT: thanks for the comments. I've made this community wiki, but left it in so others can see the comments.

Comment: No there can be valid use cases for this. For example there are compilers which output to c as immediate code and put a 
"if (break) break_into_debugger()" on each line to provide a platform independent debugging solution.

Comment: Actually on deeply pipelined processors branch prediction errors are extremely expensive, since they require a complete pipeline flush.  20x as expensive as an instruction execution is a reasonable estimate.  If his benchmarks are telling him that he's got a problem with branch prediction then he's doing the right thing.  VTune gives you very good data on this btw, if you haven't tried it.