# What is the advantage of GCC's __builtin_expect in if else statements?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, built-in, likely-unlikely

I came across a `#define` in which they use `__builtin_expect`.

[The documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-g_t_005f_005fbuiltin_005fexpect-4159) says:

> #### Built-in Function: `long __builtin_expect (long exp, long c)`
>
> You may use `__builtin_expect` to provide the compiler with branch
>   prediction information. In general, you should prefer to use actual
>   profile feedback for this (`-fprofile-arcs`), as programmers are
>   notoriously bad at predicting how their programs actually perform.
>   However, there are applications in which this data is hard to collect.
>
> The return value is the value of `exp`, which should be an integral
>   expression. The semantics of the built-in are that it is expected that
>   `exp == c`. For example:
>
> ```
>       if (__builtin_expect (x, 0))
>         foo ();
> ```
>
> would indicate that we do not expect to call `foo`, since we expect `x` to be zero.

So why not directly use:

```
if (x)
    foo ();
```

instead of the complicated syntax with `__builtin_expect`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [likely()/unlikely() macros in the Linux kernel - how do they work? What's their benefit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109710/likely-unlikely-macros-in-the-linux-kernel-how-do-they-work-whats-their)

Comment: I think your *direct* code should have been `if ( x == 0) {} else foo();`.. or simply `if ( x != 0 ) foo();` which is equivalent to the code from GCC documentation.

Answer (score 250, accepted):

Imagine the assembly code that would be generated from:

```
if (__builtin_expect(x, 0)) {
    foo();
    ...
} else {
    bar();
    ...
}
```

I guess it should be something like:

```
  cmp   $x, 0
  jne   _foo
_bar:
  call  bar
  ...
  jmp   after_if
_foo:
  call  foo
  ...
after_if:
```

You can see that the instructions are arranged in such an order that the `bar` case precedes the `foo` case (as opposed to the C code). This can utilise the CPU pipeline better, since a jump thrashes the already fetched instructions.

Before the jump is executed, the instructions below it (the `bar` case) are pushed to the pipeline. Since the `foo` case is unlikely, jumping too is unlikely, hence thrashing the pipeline is unlikely.

Comment: Does it really work like that? Why the foo definition can't come first? The order of function definitions are irrelevant, as far as you have a prototype, right?

Comment: This is not about function definitions. It is about rearranging the machine code in a way that causes a smaller probability for the CPU to fetch instructions that are not going to be executed.

Comment: Ohh i understand. So you mean since there is a high probability for `x = 0` so the bar is given first. And foo, is defined later since it's chances (rather use probability) is less, right?

Comment: Really it makes sense. But do you have any reference which states this is how should be the ordering of instructions, when one has greater probability than the other?

Comment: This may also embed hints for the CPU [branch predictor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor), improving pipelining

Comment: This also places the most likely case closer to the comparison, such that it might be on the same cache line (and the unlikely case might not be in the instruction cache at all).

Comment: @Nik-Lz no, the effects of that jump should be accounted for by the branch predictor.  One assumption for __builtin_expect is usually that all things are not equal... there is a slow path and a fast path, and you as the programmer happen to know which path is most likely to be used.

Comment: I have doubts about this. I heard modern branch predictors will follow the most "likely" path anyway (depending on what happened at this location on previous paths), so it doesn't really matter how you arrange things (it's even the base of Spectre and Meltdown attacks).

Comment: @maxbc It is true that the branch predictor can learn, but during the first (couple) pass(es), it doesn't have any data to predict from. In that case, static branch prediction is used, and this construct lets the compiler generate assembly such that the static branch prediction will predict the likely branch.

Comment: As for the example, I think an even more efficient implementation saving at least one instruction is placing the unexpected branch (_foo()) somewhere else completely and let it have an unconditional jump back to where the branching happened (if) or ended (if/else). This will avoid the unconditional jmp in the expected branch, and avoid dispatching any of the instructions in the unexpected branch because of dispatching multiple instructions every clock cycle. (This assuming I remember and understand PowerPC 74xx manual right.)

Comment: You really don't need a builtin to control the compiler though.  In C/C++ the fastest path (branch predictor notwithstanding) is to assume the IF is true.  I.e., arrange your expression such that the ELSE clause (if any) is the least expected path.  Static branch predictors without any entries in the BTB will assume (on modern x86 and ARM processors) that a branch is not taken.  Earlier x86 processors had different assumptions depending on whether the branch was backwards or forwards, but the general assumptions are IFs are true and loops will continue looping.

Comment: A good amount of CPUs without branch predictor defaults to “predict that forward jumps are not taken, predict that backward jumps are taken” (the latter are most often loops). Of these with branch predictor, many default to this before they have collected any information from passing these branches, though there are some notable exceptions (some individual CPU models from notable vendors). If not optimising for one model specifically, doing this most basic of reordering is more worth than harm still.

Answer (score 73):

**Let's decompile to see what GCC 4.8 does with it**

Blagovest mentioned branch inversion to improve the pipeline, but do current compilers really do it? Let's find out!

**Without `__builtin_expect`**

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "time.h"

int main() {
    /* Use time to prevent it from being optimized away. */
    int i = !time(NULL);
    if (i)
        puts("a");
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and decompile with GCC 4.8.2 x86_64 Linux:

```
gcc -c -O3 -std=gnu11 main.c
objdump -dr main.o
```

Output:

```
0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
   4:       31 ff                   xor    %edi,%edi
   6:       e8 00 00 00 00          callq  b <main+0xb>
                    7: R_X86_64_PC32        time-0x4
   b:       48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
   e:       75 0a                   jne    1a <main+0x1a>
  10:       bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
                    11: R_X86_64_32 .rodata.str1.1
  15:       e8 00 00 00 00          callq  1a <main+0x1a>
                    16: R_X86_64_PC32       puts-0x4
  1a:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  1c:       48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  20:       c3                      retq
```

The instruction order in memory was unchanged: first the `puts` and then `retq` return.

**With `__builtin_expect`**

Now replace `if (i)` with:

```
if (__builtin_expect(i, 0))
```

and we get:

```
0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
   4:       31 ff                   xor    %edi,%edi
   6:       e8 00 00 00 00          callq  b <main+0xb>
                    7: R_X86_64_PC32        time-0x4
   b:       48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
   e:       74 07                   je     17 <main+0x17>
  10:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  12:       48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  16:       c3                      retq
  17:       bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
                    18: R_X86_64_32 .rodata.str1.1
  1c:       e8 00 00 00 00          callq  21 <main+0x21>
                    1d: R_X86_64_PC32       puts-0x4
  21:       eb ed                   jmp    10 <main+0x10>
```

The `puts` was moved to the very end of the function, the `retq` return!

The new code is basically the same as:

```
int i = !time(NULL);
if (i)
    goto puts;
ret:
return 0;
puts:
puts("a");
goto ret;
```

This optimization was not done with `-O0`.

But good luck on writing an example that runs faster with `__builtin_expect` than without, [CPUs are really smart those days](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1851905/895245). My naive attempts [are here](https://github.com/cirosantilli/assembly-cheat/tree/ba3b76cd4530268d4c34e29c354d399c0d8552fc/compiler-generated/gcc/interactive).

**C++20 `[[likely]]` and `[[unlikely]]`**

C++20 has standardized those C++ built-ins: [How to use C++20's likely/unlikely attribute in if-else statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51797959/how-to-use-c20s-likely-unlikely-attribute-in-if-else-statement) They will likely (a pun!) do the same thing.

Comment: Check out libdispatch's dispatch_once function, which uses __builtin_expect for a practical optimization. The slow path runs one-time-ever and exploits __builtin_expect to hint the branch predictor that the fast path should be taken. The fast path runs without using any locks at all! https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-06-06-secrets-of-dispatch_once.html

Comment: Doesn't appear to make any difference in GCC 9.2: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GzP6cx (actually, already in 8.1)

Comment: By saying "CPUs are really smart" you imply they are all using out-of-order, dynamic execution, which is not true, as long as there are other CPU architectures — in-order, explicitly scheduled at compile time.

Answer (score 47):

The idea of `__builtin_expect` is to tell the compiler that you'll usually find that the expression evaluates to c, so that the compiler can optimize for that case.

I'd guess that someone thought they were being clever and that they were speeding things up by doing this.

Unfortunately, unless the situation is **very well understood** (it's likely that they have done no such thing), it may well have made things worse. The documentation even says:

> In general, you should prefer to use actual profile feedback for this (`-fprofile-arcs`), as programmers are notoriously bad at predicting how their programs actually perform. However, there are applications in which this data is hard to collect.

In general, you shouldn't be using `__builtin_expect` unless:

- You have a very real performance issue
- You've already optimized the algorithms in the system appropriately
- You've got performance data to back up your assertion that a particular case is the most likely

Comment: Yes, i think it is like that, but somewhere i see i need to understand the concept of branch prediction as you and Kerrek have said, it may flash more light in that. I think it takes place during syntatic analysis, right?

Comment: @kindsmasher1 - the idea of branch prediction is that the underlying processor compare and branch instructions are often faster in one direction than the other (for instance, not taking the branch may be quicker than taking the branch). If the processor knows what value is most likely, and therefore which half of the if is most likely to be taken, it can pick compare operations and branch instructions to maximize the speed of that most likely branch. Note that it can also do things at a higher level and re-arrange your code, if that makes the most sense.

Comment: @Michael: That's not really a description of branch prediction.

Comment: "most programmers are BAD" or anyway no better than the compiler. Any idiot can tell that in a for loop, the continuation condition is likely to be true, but the compiler knows that too so there's no benefit telling it. If for some reason you wrote a loop that would almost always break immediately, and if you can't provide profile data to the compiler for PGO, *then* maybe the programmer knows something the compiler doesn't.

Comment: In some situations, it doesn't matter which branch is more likely, but rather which branch matters. If the unexpected branch leads to abort(), then likelihood doesn't matter, and the expected branch should be given performance-priority when optimizing.

Comment: The problem with your claim is that the optimizations the CPU can perform with respect to branch probability is pretty much limited to one: branch prediction, and _this optimization happens whether you use `__builtin_expect` or not_. On the other hand, the compiler can perform many optimizations based on the branch probability, such as organizing the code so the hot path is contiguous, moving code unlikely to be optimized further away or reducing its size, taking decisions about which branches to vectorize, better scheduling the hot path, and so on.

Comment: ... without information from the developer, it is blind and chooses a neutral strategy. If the developer is right about the probabilities (and in many cases it is trivial to understand that a branch is usually taken/not taken) - you get these benefits. If you aren't you get some penalty, but it is not somehow much larger than the benefits, and most critically, none of this somehow _overrides_ the CPU branch prediction.

Comment: Well, actually, sometimes it's clever to use. E.g. AMD are [using it in their driver](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/tree/src/gallium/drivers/radeonsi/si_state_draw.c?id=6a1d9684f4ec1e1eed49bc14749be7b7784277ec#n997). The `linkely()`/`unlikely()` functions you see is a macros to `__builtin_expect()`. The *(si_)* `draw_vbo()` is called 5k…7.5k times per second in GTAⅣ, so it's quite a thing to optimize.

Comment: @Hi-Angel - which is what I said - if you actually HAVE performance data and understand the situation, then sure it makes sense. And the folks doing GTA DO have the data and DO know the situation. They are BY FAR in the minority and are among the few who should be using __builtin_expect.

Comment: Yeah, it's called a lot in every game. That said, the GTAⅣ measurements are actually mine, obtained with `GALLIUM_HUD=draw-calls` variable *(tho with r600 driver, not radeonsi)*. Judging from IRC discussion, 7.5k is too much, modern games do around 4k.

Answer (score 14):

Well, as it says in the description, the first version adds a predictive element to the construction, telling the compiler that the `x == 0` branch is the more likely one - that is, it's the branch that will be taken more often by your program.

With that in mind, the compiler can optimize the conditional so that it requires the least amount of work when the expected condition holds, at the expense of maybe having to do more work in case of the unexpected condition.

Take a look at how conditionals are implemented during the compilation phase, and also in the resulting assembly, to see how one branch may be less work than the other.

However, I would only expect this optimization to have noticeable effect if the conditional in question is part of a tight inner loop that gets called a *lot*, since the difference in the resulting code is relatively small. And if you optimize it the wrong way round, you may well decrease your performance.

Comment: But at the end it is all about checking the condition by the compiler, do you mean to say that the compiler always assumes this branch and proceeds, and later if there is not a match then
? What happens? I think there is something more about this branch prediction stuff in compiler design, and how it works.

Comment: This is truly a micro-optimization. Look up how conditionals are implemented, there's a small bias towards one branch. As a hypothetical example, suppose a conditional becomes a test plus a jump in the assembly. Then the jumping branch is slower than the non-jumping one, so you'd prefer to make the expected branch the non-jumping one.

Comment: I better go back to my college book of `compiler design - Aho, Ullmann, Sethi` :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: I think, you got it wrong. You said *"`x != 0` branch is the more likely one"*, I think `x==0` branch is more likely one, because it says `if (__builtin_expect(x, 0)) foo(); `.. i.e if `foo()` will be executed only if `x` is *not* `0`. which means the `if` is  `x!=0` branch, and the implicit `else` is `x==0` branch, which is more likely to be executed, as `x` is expected to be `0`. Note that `__builtin_expect` returns the first argument passed to it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any of the answers addressing the question that I think you were asking, paraphrased:

> Is there a more portable way of hinting branch prediction to the compiler.

The title of your question made me think of doing it this way:

```
if ( !x ) {} else foo();
```

If the compiler assumes that 'true' is more likely, it could optimize for not calling `foo()`.

The problem here is just that you don't, in general, know what the compiler will assume -- so any code that uses this kind of technique would need to be carefully measured (and possibly monitored over time if the context changes).

Comment: This may have, in fact, been exactly what the OP had originally intended to type (as indicated by the title) -- but for some reason the use of `else` was left out of the body of the post.

Answer (score 1):

I test it on Mac according @Blagovest Buyukliev and @Ciro.  The assembles look clear and I add comments;

Commands are 
`gcc -c -O3 -std=gnu11 testOpt.c;  otool -tVI testOpt.o`

When I use  -O3 ，  it looks the same no matter the  __builtin_expect(i, 0) exist or not.

```
testOpt.o:
(__TEXT,__text) section
_main:
0000000000000000    pushq   %rbp     
0000000000000001    movq    %rsp, %rbp    // open function stack
0000000000000004    xorl    %edi, %edi       // set time args 0 (NULL)
0000000000000006    callq   _time      // call time(NULL)
000000000000000b    testq   %rax, %rax   // check time(NULL)  result
000000000000000e    je  0x14           //  jump 0x14 if testq result = 0， namely jump to puts
0000000000000010    xorl    %eax, %eax   //  return 0   ,  return appear first 
0000000000000012    popq    %rbp    //  return 0
0000000000000013    retq                     //  return 0
0000000000000014    leaq    0x9(%rip), %rdi  ## literal pool for: "a"  // puts  part, afterwards
000000000000001b    callq   _puts
0000000000000020    xorl    %eax, %eax
0000000000000022    popq    %rbp
0000000000000023    retq
```

When compile with  -O2 ，  it looks different with and without __builtin_expect(i, 0)

First without

```
testOpt.o:
(__TEXT,__text) section
_main:
0000000000000000    pushq   %rbp
0000000000000001    movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000000000004    xorl    %edi, %edi
0000000000000006    callq   _time
000000000000000b    testq   %rax, %rax
000000000000000e    jne 0x1c       //   jump to 0x1c if not zero, then return
0000000000000010    leaq    0x9(%rip), %rdi ## literal pool for: "a"   //   put part appear first ,  following   jne 0x1c
0000000000000017    callq   _puts
000000000000001c    xorl    %eax, %eax     // return part appear  afterwards
000000000000001e    popq    %rbp
000000000000001f    retq
```

Now with  __builtin_expect(i, 0)

```
testOpt.o:
(__TEXT,__text) section
_main:
0000000000000000    pushq   %rbp
0000000000000001    movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000000000004    xorl    %edi, %edi
0000000000000006    callq   _time
000000000000000b    testq   %rax, %rax
000000000000000e    je  0x14   // jump to 0x14 if zero  then put. otherwise return 
0000000000000010    xorl    %eax, %eax   // return appear first 
0000000000000012    popq    %rbp
0000000000000013    retq
0000000000000014    leaq    0x7(%rip), %rdi ## literal pool for: "a"
000000000000001b    callq   _puts
0000000000000020    jmp 0x10
```

To summarize,  __builtin_expect works in the last case.

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases, you should leave the branch prediction as it is and you do not need to worry about it.

One case where it is beneficial is CPU intensive algorithms with a lot of branching. In some cases, the jumps could lead the to exceed the current CPU program cache making the CPU wait for the next part of the software to run. By pushing the unlikely branches at the end, you will keep your memory close and only jump for unlikely cases.