# Can a heap object whose initial address is not stored be protected from garbage collection?

Tags: c, pointers, garbage-collection

Suppose that

- I am modifying someone else's C program;
- a garbage collector is active;
- there exists an object on the heap I do not want the garbage collector to reap; and
- the object lives until the program exits, so it is unnecessary to free() it.

Must I store the object's *initial* address?  Suppose that I don't care about the initial address.  Suppose instead that I only care about some pointers into the object's interior, and that these pointers are all I store.  Suppose that I throw the initial address away.

Will the garbage collector reap my object?

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

The program does not now collect garbage as far as I know. However, if a future revision of the program began to collect garbage, then the code I am adding today might suddenly turn into a hard-to-find bug. I don't want to make a hard-to-find bug; but the program is an old, stable program thousands of users have used for many years. The program is thus known to function acceptably under a wide variety of real conditions. Redesign is not an option.

The program employs global data structures it never bothers to free(). This is the design within which I must work.

If you want to know: the pointers I wish to store—the pointers that point into their objects' interiors—happen to point to words within an ASCII string. I care only about the words, not about the whole string.  Especially, I don't care about whitespace at the start of the string, which is why I don't care about the string's initial address; but a garbage collector might inadvertently care, mightn't it?

It seems silly to store a linked list of pointers neither I nor anyone else will ever use, just to fend off a hypothetical garbage collector that does not exist; but I'd store the list if truly necessary.

Or is my concern groundless? Does no one ever add garbage collection to old C programs, anyway?

Comment: C? Garbage collection? Does not compute...

Comment: @John3136: Personally, I know very little about garbage collection, which is why I ask. However, the ubiquitous Hans-J. Boehm [seems to think](https://www.hboehm.info/gc/) that garbage collection is possible with C. Why he thinks that, I don't know. I am at least as confused as you are.

Comment: Everything is possible - always has been. Why do you think you need to worry about it?

Comment: @John3136: The bug in question would be an invitation to a stack-smashing attack, a potential security hole, on thousands of public-facing servers.

Comment: @John3136 IIRC, C specifically allows for garbage-collected implementations, and there *are* C garbage collectors, they're just not widely used.

Comment: @immibis As I said "Everything is possible". But if you have a legacy system with no GC why would you consider adding GC? Why would you worry about whether your coding practices work with one particular (as yet unidentified) GC implementation? I'd worry more about aliens infecting my hardware with a virus than I would about adding GC to a legacy system!

Comment: When and how do you access the data at the start of the structure given that you only store pointers to the interior of the structure?  If the answer is "you don't", then why are you storing the data before the lowest addressed pointer to the interior, thus avoiding the angst.  If you do access the start, can you do something like add a pointer to the start of the structure within the structure?  Is there only one of these objects, or are there many of them?  If there's only one, you can surely simply store a pointer to the start of it somewhere to prevent the GC from collecting it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Those are all good questions. Basically, I am hacking a legacy design which, in its own, premodern way, is already debugged and it works. This means that I ought to change as little as possible. Your idea to store a pointer to the start of the object *somewhere* makes sense; I'll probably do that. Regarding the data before the lowest addressed pointer, it's whitespace at the start of a heap-allocated ASCII string. But, one may ask, doesn't the string need to be deallocated? Answer: in this legacy code, the storage is in a global structure that never gets destructed, so, no.

Comment: it is mighty poor programming practice for an application to depend on the OS to cleanup. However, such reliance on the OS works because as a program is exited, its' whole process space is returned to the OS as blocks of memory, including the block that was designated the 'heap', so no one cares what was happening within that process space. To avoid such angst as you have, every program 'should' cleanup all 'heap' allocations and close all files BEFORE exiting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Let us set aside the fact that a program that uses `allocate()` but not `free()` can hardly be called "stable";</sup>

<sup>Let us set aside the fact that adding garbage collection to an existing large C program that works is one of those "if there you go, only pain will you find" situations.</sup>

The answer to your question is:

**It depends on how your garbage collector works.**

If it is exotic, it may be sweeping memory and looking for pointers that point anywhere within the heap, not just to beginnings of memory blocks.  In this case, you are covered, since a pointer pointing in the middle of a string will be enough to keep the string anchored in memory.  (Prevent it from being garbage-collected.)

If it is not that exotic, then it will only be looking for pointers that point to beginnings of memory blocks.  (Which is a rather sensible thing to do.)  In which case, no, your object is not anchored unless you maintain a pointer to the object itself.

Personally, I wouldn't even try an exotic garbage collector, but that's just me.

Comment: +1 I wouldn't even try an exotic garbage collector, either. It's just that I don't know what some future developer hacking on this program might try. But, yes, maybe this is not worth worrying about. I have only noticed that [Hans-J. Boehm of the C++ standards committee seems to worry about it,](https://www.hboehm.info/gc/) so I thought that I had better ask.

Comment: Regarding stability, I am inclined to agree with you, but the kind of stability of which I speak is a different kind: the program in question has run on thousands of public-facing servers for 20 years; it works in practice for lots of people. The program is probably running right now on the server on which you and I are having this very conversation. I'd rather not be responsible for crashing that server!