# Creating a function to check if malloc succeeded

Tags: c, malloc

So I am doing a small project which involves using the `malloc`, `realloc` and `calloc` functions from time to time. I understood that after every allocation I should be checking if it failed and it points to null like so:

```
int* arr = malloc(size*sizeof(int));

if (!arr)
{
      printf("ERROR! Not enough memory!\n");
      exit(1); // to exit the program immedietly.
}
```

and I was wondering if it is okay to create a method that will do just that for every kind of pointer like so:

```
void checkOutOfMemory(const void* p) //gets a pointer and exit program if points to null.
{
    if (!p)
    {
        printf("ERROR! Out of memory!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

I mean, it works so far, but I started wondering if there are any special cases I didn't know about.

Comment: What about renaming `checkOutOfMemory()` to `checkNotNull()` ?

Comment: I suggest you don't rely on exit()

Comment: @水飲み鳥 thank you for the suggestion, I like that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a good way to perform this kind of check.  It prevents the error checking code from being duplicated in numerous places.  You should however use `perror` which will include a textual description of why `malloc` failed.

You could go one step further and perform the allocation and check at once:

```
void *safe_malloc(size_t size)
{
    void *ptr = malloc(size);

    if (!ptr && (size > 0)) {
      perror("malloc failed!");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return ptr;
}
```

Since `malloc` can return `NULL` on success if the given size is 0, you need to check for that as well.

You can then create similar functions for `realloc` and `calloc`.

Comment: For readability, I suggest `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` instead of `exit(1);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will use that

Comment: `malloc(0) == NULL` is not a `malloc()` failure.  Recommend  `if (!ptr && size > 0) {`

Comment: @chux Good call.  Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Everything is all right but just do one thing instead of printing message get the benefit of fact that `malloc` sets `errno` (Not from standard rather from Open group based spec). So do this

```
if(!p)
  perror("malloc failed");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);    
}
```

`perror` do this - appends a message generated from `strerror(errno)` to the string you are printing.(Giving you a plausible reason for the failure of `malloc`).

Also there is one thing that you must remember when you do this

```
void *p = malloc(SOMESIZE);
```

check whether `SOMESIZE == 0` because `malloc` *may* return `NULL` when you pass `0` to it. Handle that case separately. In case you get `SIZE!=0` and get `NULL` in `p` throw error.

Also `malloc`'s parameter type is `unsigned` check if that criteria is being satisfied before calling `my_malloc`.

The code will be something like,

```
void * my_malloc(size_t SIZE){
  void *p = malloc(SIZE);
  if(p == NULL && SIZE){
     perror("malloc failed");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);    
  }
  return p;
}
```

Note: The setting `errno` in `malloc` failure is specified in [Open Group Based Spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/malloc.html) (alk mentioned it).

Answer (score 1):

You can code your `malloc` like wrapper which check against failure, as [answered by dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48043838/841108).

Actually, such a function is conventionally called `xmalloc` and provided by many (free software) libraries, notably [GNU libiberty](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libiberty/). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7590254/841108).

However, some systems have [memory overcommitment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment); this is a feature that I dislike (it makes `malloc` never fail, even when your [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) is exhausted).