# Branch Prediction: Branch Order vs builtin_expect

Tags: c++, micro-optimization, branch-prediction

I am learning about branch prediction in `C++` and have a fairly straightforward question.

It seems the **`__builtin_expect`** term tells the compiler which clause to put first in the assembly code.

However if this is added manually by the programmer how is it any different than simply switching the **if**/**else** clauses in the `C++` code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do we use \_\_builtin\_expect when a straightforward way is to use if-else](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346929/why-do-we-use-builtin-expect-when-a-straightforward-way-is-to-use-if-else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler's optimiser is allowed to reorder branches. The __builtin_expect is useful if the compiler gets (or is likely) to get it wrong.