# Can using `__builtin_expect` affect program semantics?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

GCC (and Clang also), provide this `__builtin_expect` for human-assisted branch prediction, as explained [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html). Informally, people explain its semantics in the following way: "compiler just processes the indicated branch unconditionally, and if the condition should turn out to be different than indicated, an expensive roll-back takes place".

But if I have a piece of code as the following:

```
if (__builtin_expect(p != 0, 1)) // line 1
  p->access_object();            // line 2
```

If I treated the informal explanation above literally, the compiler can just execute line 2 without waiting for the computation of the condition in line 1, and therefore cause an undefined behavior (null pointer dereference), should the pointer happen to be null.

My question is, if I use `__builtin_expect` do I still get the guarantee, that my defensive checks work? And if so, do I get any run-time benefit if I use `__builtin_expect` in defensive checks as the above one?

(Note: my goal for using `__builtin_expect` like this is to get the maximum performance for the cases where `p` is non-null, at the expense of slowing down (even by orders of magnitude) the cases where `p` is null; Even if the latter case appears quite often.)

Comment: IMO that's a bad informal description, afaik it just optimizes for whichever branch you told it to. And that belief seems to be backed up by [answers to a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7346929/583833)

Comment: @Borgleader: so this says that the check is performed first anyway. The only question is whether the execution can continue immediately after the check, or some time after the check. Did I get it right?

Comment: I'd say the compiler doesn't "process the indicated branch unconditionally". It *starts* to process it unconditionally, but the discards any results if a wrong branch was chosed. This discard happens on a very low level. These unconditionally computed results won't even end up in actual RAM before the condition is checked. Also, as far as I know, even without `__builtin_expect` one of the braches would always be chosen before checking the condition, but it would be chosed by the branch predictor instead of you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, builtin_expect will not affect the semantics of a race-free program.

In particular, the compiler must not emit code which would execute the body of the `if` block if that code has side effects which cannot be undone.  The code must be "as if" `builtin_expect` were not used, apart from performance.

For your specific example:

```
if (__builtin_expect(p != 0, 1)) // line 1
  p->access_object();            // line 2
```

`p` cannot be dereferenced if it is null.  So what is the point of `builtin_expect` in this case?  The most it can do is tell the compiler "`p` is probably not null, so `access_object()` will probably be called."  If the definition of `access_object()` is `inline`, the compiler will probably try to inline it, whereas if you said "`p` is probably null," the compiler might decide it was better not to inline the code for `access_object()` at this call site, because it is unlikely to be used.

In fact, this leads to a non-intuitive use of `builtin_expect` in practice: you can use to mean "this code is the slow path," regardless of how "likely" it is.  As a trivial example, a server program might do this:

```
if (__builtin_expect(is_allowed(user, request), 1))
    process(request);
else
    reject(request);
```

Even if we find that 50% of requests are illegitimate and will be rejected, we might still decide to mark the "happy path" as likely taken, because we do not care about slowing down rejections.

Comment: Yes, in fact this is my motivation: not to show which branch occurs more often, but to show which one I want optimized.