# Double boolean negation operator

Tags: c++, c, macros, negation

I came across this piece of code from the [Microsoft implementation of GSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL) (the C++ Guideline Support Library):

```
#if defined(__clang__) || defined(__GNUC__)
#define GSL_LIKELY(x) __builtin_expect(!!(x), 1)
#define GSL_UNLIKELY(x) __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0)
#else
#define GSL_LIKELY(x) (!!(x))
#define GSL_UNLIKELY(x) (!!(x))
#endif
```

I read about the `__builtin_expect` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109710/how-do-the-likely-and-unlikely-macros-in-the-linux-kernel-work-and-what-is-t) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346929/why-do-we-use-builtin-expect-when-a-straightforward-way-is-to-use-if-else)), but it is still unclear to me what is the purpose of the double boolean negation operator in `(!!(x))`. Why is it used?

The file in question is [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/gsl_assert).

Comment: @dhke This answer could be adapted to C++. In C++ operator! return a boolean.

Comment: Why is this question tagged C when the context is a strictly C++ library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__builtin_expect` works with strict equality, so the point of double negation here is to make sure all truthy values are converted to 1 (and thus match the 1 in `GSL_LIKELY`), and all the falsy values match the 0 in `GSL_UNLIKELY`.

The double negation is kept even if `__builtin_expect` is not available to keep uniformity (as the caller may store the return value for other uses besides as a condition in an `if`).