# Performance of duplicating vs deduplicating identical conditional code in loops

Tags: c, performance, assembly, optimization, x86-64

Say I have code like this, call it version 1:

```
while (some_condition) {
    // .. work that may trigger rare_condition ...

    if (rare_condition) {
        // .. rare work here ..
        continue;
    }

    // .. work that may trigger rare_condition ...

    if (rare_condition) {
        // .. rare work here ..
        continue;
    }

    // .. more work
}
```

Assume that the "rare work" is identical across both cases. We could equivalently write version 2:

```
while (some_condition) {
    // .. work that may trigger rare_condition ...

    if (rare_condition) {
        goto rare_work;
    }

    // .. work that may trigger rare_condition ...

    if (rare_condition) {
        goto rare_work;
    }

    // .. more work
    continue;

  rare_work:
    // .. rare work here ..
}
```

The compiler should usually be smart enough to make the `if()` checks result in a jump directly to `rare_work`, rather than a jump to a block containing a jump to `rare_work`. The compiler may even transform version 1 to version 2 for us, because it reduces the overall amount of assembly, increasing the chance of fitting in instruction cache.

My question is: if instruction cache is *not* an issue, is there any reason to expect one or the other to perform better? This is assuming we care about low level micro-optimization and are willing to write the code in assembly, if we have to in order to force getting one version or the other. I realize things like port availability could change based on what the work instructions actually are, I'm just wondering if there is any high level reason to expect a difference before doing such an analysis.

Comment: Some people are not going to like this, but there is a version three that eliminates one goto: `if (rare_condition) { rare_work: /* Rare work here. */ continue; } … if (rare_condition) goto rare_work; …`.

Comment: Those two proposed structures are not equivalent in terms of code and control flow.

Comment: @ErikEidt I think jumping in a branch block with a goto is the perfect way to cause complex bugs and make the code less maintainable, especially if the loop is big with many conditions.

Comment: Note you can tell the compiler that the condition are rare so it can make the loop code more contiguous (and cache friendly) and avoid necessary jumps in a middle of the loop. This is done with  famous [likely/unlikely macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109710/how-do-the-likely-unlikely-macros-in-the-linux-kernel-work-and-what-is-their-ben). They can also help some processors that still use static prediction.

Comment: @ErikEidt how so? AFAICT they continue to the next iteration under the same circumstances

Comment: The compiler cannot know the probability of the condition (unless you enable profile-guided optimizations) without the likely/unlikely. In this case, the former version is less efficient. If you add the likely/unlikely macro on the first code, it will be at least as efficient than the second one (with an optimizing compiler) and without the pretty bad `goto`. The code duplication is not great but neither a `goto`. Can't you use a (static inline) function? (e.g. return an error code and handle errors outside the function).

Comment: @JérômeRichard maintainability is outside the scope of the question, I only asked about perf on purpose. I know best practice, but low level learning is my focus ATM.

Comment: @EricPostpischil beautiful, that's what I get for thinking too much in terms of C and not asm 

Comment: Then the comment about using the macro still applies : use the first code with `unlikely(...)`. The compiler will generate conditional jump that will often not jump. These jumps are generally slightly faster. On CPU with static prediction it is better. On x86-64, mainstream CPUs typically use a dynamic TAGE predictor so no entry will even be created as long as the rare condition is not triggered (can speed up conditional branches outside the loop). The solution of EricPostpischil avoid code duplication but it should not be faster as long as the cache is not an issue (which is assumed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lundin's answer shows that compilers can make good asm with fully structured programming, avoiding even a `continue` which could avoid putting the second half inside an `else`.

Factoring your code out into a helper function may require passing addresses of locals, which *hopefully* the compiler will see through after inlining, and not actually lead to worse code-gen.  Even though the code is rare, it's probably better for it to be an inline part of this function in some out-of-the-way part, rather than an actual runtime `call`, especially if it needs read/write access to some local vars.

---

With the 2x `if()goto` version, the compiler *could* do an optimization similar to "tail duplication" to turn it into the first version. (The reverse might be less likely, although identical-code folding is possible if you write the same operations twice.)

Or into asm shaped like [@EricPostpischil's version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77803260/performance-of-duplicating-vs-deduplicating-identical-conditional-code-in-loops/77805715#comment137160936_77803260) with a goto label in one `if` body if it chose to lay out the asm so the rare_work block was the fall-through path from one of the branches.  But it's rare so we actually don't want that in the asm, we'd rather the common case was fall-through<sup>1</sup>, not jumping over the rare block.

---

**The C that's closest to the asm you want is `2x if()goto`**, which could naturally compile to an extra block past the end of the function which jumps back into the loop. (Or at least somewhere that doesn't require a jmp inside the loop to skip it).

Whether real compilers see it that way or would transform it significantly is another matter; gotta check the asm. @JérômeRichard's suggestion in comments of `if(unlikely(rare_condition)) goto` is a good idea if compilers don't put the block of rare work out-of-line.

#### Footnote 1:

Separate from branch prediction, a taken branch can reduce code-fetch bandwidth. e.g. in Intel CPUs, an unconditional branch ends a uop cache line. (And a predicted-taken conditional branch probably goes to another uop cache line anyway.)

Or if running from legacy decode (or on a non-x86 that doesn't need a uop cache), a taken branch makes later bytes of machine code useless in a 16 or 32 byte block fetched in one cycle. So for code-fetch bandwidth (and I-cache locality if the condition is truly rare), you want the common case to have mostly not-taken conditional branches.

As @JérômeRichard mentioned, never-taken branches might not even pollute branch-prediction for other branches.

The fast path should ideally be a straight line.  This is the main benefit of `likely`/`unlikely` hints, not hinting the actual runtime branch-predictor which isn't possible on most ISAs.  (See *[Is it possible to tell the branch predictor how likely it is to follow the branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851299/is-it-possible-to-tell-the-branch-predictor-how-likely-it-is-to-follow-the-branc/1851445#1851445)* and a specific example of GCC output in *[What is the advantage of GCC's __builtin_expect in if else statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346929/what-is-the-advantage-of-gccs-builtin-expect-in-if-else-statements/31540623#31540623)*)

Another aspect of `likely`/`unlikely` is hinting the compiler that the branch *is* predictable at all, so it's less likely to use `cmov` with a data dependency instead of branching.

Comment: (This answer is mostly just what I posted as comments under the question 6 hours ago, which I should have posted as an answer in the first place.  Of course, this is all just hand-waving, it's very likely that the asm *won't* match the C source layout, so this answer would be better with some Godbolt examples.  But at least Lundin has one so I don't feel like it's too misleading to have this answer up without any.)

Answer (score 5):

> My question is: if instruction cache is not an issue, is there any reason to expect one or the other to perform better?

The performance hiccup here would be the number of branches. If there is a branch prediction miss, that's when you lose performance. And the best counter measure is simply to try to reduce the number of branches. Since your code is pseudo code, there's no telling if doing so is possible. But that's what manual optimization should focus on, rather than code re-ordering.

---

From a pure readability point of view, it would be perfectly possible to rewrite the loop without any "spaghetti programming" aka continue/goto and still keep the same performance:

```c
while(some_condition) 
{
  bool is_rare;
    
  is_rare = work1();
  if(is_rare)
  {
    rare();
  }
  else
  {
    is_rare = work2();
    if(is_rare)
    {
      rare();
    }
  }
}
```

Where all functions are `static inline`. While trying this out in gcc x86 -O3 I got assembler code pretty much identical to your `goto` version, with `rare()` inlined at the bottom of the loop. Which at least proves that we don't have to write spaghetti on the C level.

Artificial example code: https://godbolt.org/z/M8EznYr1z. `.L5:` is the `rare()` function inlined.

```
do_stuff:
        sub     rsp, 24
.L12:
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rsp+15]
        test    al, al
        je      .L1
.L14:
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    puts
        cmp     BYTE PTR rare_[rip], 0
        jne     .L5
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2
        call    puts
        cmp     BYTE PTR rare_[rip], 0
        je      .L12
.L5:
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        call    puts
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rsp+15]
        test    al, al
        jne     .L14
.L1:
        add     rsp, 24
        ret
```

Comment: Agree in principle, but: "Which at least proves that we don't have to write spaghetti on the C level." I do think having to repeat the `rare()` function calls (and any variables you may need to pass along) is still somewhat spaghetti code.

Comment: @ecm: Maybe not as DRY (don't-repeat-yourself) as one would like, but *spaghetti* code has a more specific technical meaning involving unstructured control-flow, so seeing what happens is like trying to follow a strand of spaghetti on a plate.  (Unstructured in the sense of "structured programming" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming, the use of if(){}else{} nesting, not GOTO or GOTO-like statements.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I think this is a question of degree more than a binary question. It may be structured, but as you wrote it is still repetitive. In my use of the term, there are certainly various degrees of spaghettified code and this is the approach under which I commented earlier.

Comment: @ecm: My point is that spaghetti is one specific way for code to be messy / hard-to-read.  Repeating significant amounts of code (or even one long statement), leading readers to check carefully for differences, is also a problem but not one that I'd call "spaghetti".  It's a violation of the DRY principle, not of structure programming.  A solution here is GNU C nested functions, which can see their parent function's local variable, like a C++ lambda with capture.  So you define it once (where you would a lambda), and each call-site is terse, not having to pass the addresses of several locals.

Comment: @ecm In this particular little example, code repetition is not a problem. Getting obsessed about removing code repetition is however by far the most common way in which decent projects get turned into unreadable messes. With experience, one can tell when to use a bit of repetition for the sake of readability and/or performance, and when to avoid it. As a rule of thumb, KISS > DRY.