# What is the most efficient way to separate two overlapping circles?

Tags: c++, performance, math, optimization, geometry

I'm making a 2D physics engine involving dynamic balls and static surfaces. All balls are of equal mass and radius.

Typically, the process of separating ball a from b with radius r is is the following:

1. Compute the vector from the position of a to the position of b (= V).
2. Compute the magnitude of V (= m).
3. Compute the magnitude of overlap (= 2r - m = o).
4. Compute the normalized vector of v (= N).
5. Displace a and b in opposite directions by vectors (o/2)N and -(o/2)N

This is my current implementation (the math may look strange, but I managed to combine many of the aforementioned steps into one simplified equation):

```cpp
static void positionBB(Ball &a, Ball &b)
{
    Vec2 separation = Vec2::sub(b.position, a.position);
    float m = Vec2::magnitude(separation);
    if (m == 0.0f) m = 1.0f;

    float displacement = (BALL_RADIUS / m) - 0.5f;
    Vec2 dispVec = Vec2::mult(separation, displacement);

    a.position = Vec2::sub(a.position, dispVec);
    b.position = Vec2::add(b.position, dispVec);
}
```

This computation is the bottleneck in my physics engine. Can it be any better with regards to efficiency?

Edit: It may be of use to know that the radius of each ball is 0.5f. This is fixed. (For those interested, I found that having the sum of two radii equal 1 provides calculation shortcuts and optimizations).

Comment: From my understanding of Geometry:  All circles have an origin and a radius.  You may be able to separate circles by moving the origin, or reducing the radius, or both.  You may want to change to Polar Coordinates when dealing with circles.

Comment: Can you please be more precise in your post? Are you talking balls, i.e. the synonym for spheres, which are 3D shapes, or are you talking about circles, which are 2D shapes?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans 2D. I've edited the post.

Comment: I don't see obvious ways to speed up this calculation, but perhaps you can avoid it altogether? What it is supposed to accomplish? If you move ball 1 away from ball 2, ball 1 will probably meet balls 3, 4, and 25 in the next frame and you will need to move those apart again. Maybe give up the goal to separate the balls by exactly r at each step. Move them by amount proportional to say m^2-r^2, or (m/r)^2-1, they will settle at m=r, and you will save lots of square root calculations.  Just a wild guess.

Comment: This code doesn't check if the balls overlap at all (if `m` is lower than `2*BALL_RADIUS`), and would displace the balls in the wrong direction if not.

But the slowest part is likely the square root computation that is needed for `Vec2::magnitude `.

So if such a check is added, it would be better to compare the squared m with `4* BALL_RADIUS*BALL_RADIUS` instead (squared m can be calculated as sum of squares of  separation components, without taking square root).
And then only square root it if the check succeeds.

Comment: @tmlen The check for overlap has already been done. You can assume these balls are overlapping

Comment: Also knowing that `separation[0]` and `separation[1]` must be in [-1.0, +1.0] when the circles overlap, it may be possible to make a 2D lookup table (for example of 256x256 resolution) that gives the corresponding values for `dispVec`.
And the lookup table would only need to include cases where both `separation[0]` and `separation[1]` are positive, and `separation[0] >= separation[1]` (the other cases can be calculated from those I think)

Comment: Usually, checking for overlapping bounding boxes (AABBs) is the first check you do - since it's simple and cheap and if it fails you don't have to do any complicated math.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** This code is typically **latency-bound**. While the latency can be slightly improved, reducing it is hard because the code is already small (and the gain will be limited anyway). To improve the performance of such a code, it is critical to *make it more throughput-bound* (latency-bound codes are inherently inefficient). This means `positionBB` should be adapted to operate on multiple items simultaneously and especially that the code calling it must be too. This transformation is a part of a bigger approach called [**data-oriented design**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-oriented_design).

---

### Throughput improvements

Modern mainstream processors can execute [multiple instructions in parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction-level_parallelism) as long as they are independent. Since this code is mostly a chain of dependent instructions, only a fraction of the processor resources can be used for the computation (only the two last lines can be done in parallel). That being said, if this function is inlined and called for multiple items, a good processor may be able to execute instructions coming from multiple calls in parallel. But, still, the latency of the generated instructions is sufficiently big for this not to be enough to saturate the execution units of the target processor anyway (called *ports*). Indeed, for example, the latency of the instruction `subps` is 4 cycles on mainstream Intel CPUs and there are 2 SIMD (SSE) ports. The same thing is true for `addps` and `mulps`. Some instructions like `sqrtps` have a latency of 12 cycle but a reciprocal throughput of 3. Overall, you should at least operate on 4 balls simultaneously on such a CPU to **hide the latency of the instructions**. Working on 8 of them simultaneously might be even faster. Note that results on AMD Zen-like processors should be similar. Put it shortly, you can operate on more balls for free (almost).

That being said, operating on too many balls simultaneously can cause **register spilling** which is detrimental for performance. Enabling AVX on x86-64 CPU can help compilers to use more register and avoid spilling (even better with AVX-512). You need to **check the code generated by your compiler** to see if register spilling happens. If it does, then you should certainly operate on less balls simultaneously.

Additionally, the `Vec2` class operates on 2 floating-point items, but all mainstream processor architectures have SIMD units of 4 x 32-bits. This means 2 **SIMD lanes are just wasted** (50% of 128-bits SIMD registers). Even worse: most x86-64 CPUs ([>96.4%](https://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey)) can operate on at least 256-bit SIMD registers (AVX), so 6 lanes are wasted using AVX (75%). In this case, on x86-64, compilers will certainly generate a code using SSE (128-bit) which is also sub-optimal (AFAIR SSE instruction often cannot be executed on dedicated AVX port -- only on AVX ports fusing 2 SSE ones). To solve this problem, you should operate on at least 2 balls simultaneously and use the `Vec4` class instead. On not-too-old x86-64 CPUs, you should use a `Vec8` class (and possibly create it).

---

### Latency/instruction improvements

It is not clear what instructions `Vec2::magnitude` is going to generate on x86-64 CPUs, but I expect a combination of `mulps`, `shufps`+`addss` (or `haddps`) and `sqrtps`. This sequence of instruction has a significant latency (especially due to the last instruction) and poorly benefit from the SIMD instruction set (the square root is a *scalar* one while many can be done for free for nearly the same time). The division by `m` is expensive too.

On x86-64 CPUs, you can use the much more efficient **`rsqrtss`** instruction instead of a `sqrtps`+`divps`. It computes `1.f / sqrtf(x)` faster, but with a significantly less precision. You can then multiply the result by `BALL_RADIUS` and subtract 0.5f to it with a single FMA instruction (requires the FMA instruction set -- supported on most CPUs -- to be enabled). You can improve the precision by computing 1 or 2 iterations of the newton approximation (at the expense of a slower code). This strategy is mainly useful on most CPUs to increase the throughput of the code, but not much to reduce its latency. Note that some compilers might already generate this with fast-math flags.

The condition will typically generate a sub-optimal conditional jump which will be often taken. This is better to tell the compiler that this will often not be the case so it can generate a conditional jump that is often not taken (slightly faster in practice on most CPUs). This is achieved with the (compiler-dependent) [likely/unlikely macros and `__builtin_expect`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346929/what-is-the-advantage-of-gccs-builtin-expect-in-if-else-statements) or the [C++20 attribute for that](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/likely).