# Is it possible to aid branch prediction?

Tags: c++, c, branch-prediction

Can you intentionally write code in a specific way so that the branch predictor will choose the option that will be the case most of the times. For example error checks whether a resource was loaded. If this is possible how can you use this to your advantage?

Comment: Why did you tag with so many languages? The answer for C is going to be different from the answer for Java.

Comment: Might an answer also be *hardware* dependent?

Comment: How is this an exploit?  Branch prediction isn't a bug...

Comment: A more interesting question is could you exploit the branch predictor to launch a timing attack on a crypto algorithm. Although I guess most of those avoid branching in the critical bits to keep them constant time to begin with.

Comment: Always relevant in this context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array

Comment: Do you mean something like [_builtin_expect](http://blog.man7.org/2012/10/how-much-do-builtinexpect-likely-and.html)?

Comment: @ScottHunter "exploit" has a meaning outside of IT security, which is "use something to your advantage".

Comment: I [updated your title](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38193299/3) to be "aid" instead of "exploit" as I feel it fits the nature of what you are asking; however, if I'm wrong you may [edit] your question to clarify

Comment: @immibis: I was referring to the "exploit" tag, which is not for the meaning you allude to.

Comment: [Is there a compiler hint for GCC to force branch prediction to always go a certain way?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30130930/1708801) has a lot of discussion about how useful this can/can not be.

Comment: Avoid using branches would certainly help the predictor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using GCC you can use the macros [`likely()/unlikely()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/109710).

Comment: "how can you use this to your advantage?"

Comment: For most targets, telling the compiler which is more likely doesn't change the success rate of runtime branch prediction.  Most ISAs don't have branch hints that can be embedded into machine code.  Where it helps is laying out the code of a function so the likely path is contiguous (fewer I-cache lines touched, fewer *taken* branches), as Ciro's answer on the linked Q&A shows.  Or to hint the compiler's choice between branchy vs. branchless code: if it almost always goes one way, a branch can be cheaper than computing both sides and branchlessly selecting, if that was even legal.

Comment: See [Is it possible to tell the branch predictor how likely it is to follow the branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1851299) for details, e.g. my answer mentions Pentium 4 having had branch hints, but other x86 CPUs ignoring them.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, yes. Effectively speaking NO. You won't really get any benefit, try it out yourself.

With the way modern hardware works your CPU will still grind out all of the branches no matter what you do. But it doesn't really matter because they will do it concurrently.

To attempt to do it yourself you would need to use assembly language. Compiler hints like shown above will not do much.

Comment: This reads a lot more like a comment than an answer. Can you explain HOW you can "theoretically" do it, instead of just saying yes.

Comment: I didn't say yes I said no.