# What's the point of "unlikely()"?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, c-preprocessor, likely-unlikely

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [likely/unlikely macros in the Linux kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109710/likely-unlikely-macros-in-the-linux-kernel)

In the Linux kernel, I came across the line in [./linux/include/shed.h](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.9/include/linux/sched.h#L2283):

```
 if (unlikely(atomic_dec_and_test(&mm->mm_count)))
```

What exactly is the point of unlikely?  I've found a definition of it in [.arch/x86/tools/insn_sanity.c](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.9/arch/x86/tools/insn_sanity.c#L31), but it's just:

```
#define unlikely(cond) (cond)
```

To me there doesn't seem to be a point to using `unlikely()` at all.  What is the intended purpose of `unlikely`?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109710/likely-unlikely-macros-in-the-linux-kernel

Comment: @AbdiasSoftware Thanks! I didn't find that when searching SO.

Comment: I voted to close since it's an exact duplicate.