# Semantics of GCC hot attribute

Tags: optimization, gcc

Assume I have a compilation unit consisting of three functions, A, B, and C.  A is invoked once from a function external to the compilation unit (e.g. it's an entry point or callback); B is invoked many times by A (e.g. it's invoked in a tight loop); C is invoked once by each invocation of B (e.g. it's a library function).

The entire path through A (passing through B and C) is performance-critical, though the performance of A itself is non-critical (as most time is spent in B and C).

What is the minimal set of functions which one should annotate with `__attribute__ ((hot))` to effect more aggressive optimization of this path?  Assume we cannot use `-fprofile-generate`.

Equivalently: Does `__attribute__ ((hot))` mean "optimize the body of this function", "optimize calls to this function", "optimize all descendant calls this function makes", or some combination thereof?

The GCC info page does not clearly address these questions.

Comment: `__attribute__ ((hot))` may gain you something, but you might get better results from first making both B and C `static inline` and optimizing with `-O3`.

Comment: I'm assuming those steps have already been taken.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Official documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html):

> `hot`
>   The hot attribute on a function is used to inform the compiler that the function is a hot spot of the compiled program. The function is optimized more aggressively and on many target it is placed into special subsection of the text section so all hot functions appears close together improving locality.
>   When profile feedback is available, via -fprofile-use, hot functions are automatically detected and this attribute is ignored.
>
> The hot attribute on functions is not implemented in GCC versions earlier than 4.3.
>
> The hot attribute on a label is used to inform the compiler that path following the label are more likely than paths that are not so annotated. This attribute is used in cases where __builtin_expect cannot be used, for instance with computed goto or asm goto.
>
> The hot attribute on labels is not implemented in GCC versions earlier than 4.8.

[2007](http://axon.cs.byu.edu/~adam/gatheredinfo/tips/tips_gcc.php):

```
 __attribute__((hot))
```

> Hint that the marked function is "hot" and should be optimized more aggresively and/or placed near other "hot" functions (for cache locality).

[Gilad Ben-Yossef](http://benyossef.com/helping-the-compiler-help-you/):

> As their name suggests, these function attributes are used to hint the compiler that the corresponding functions are called often in your code (hot) or seldom called (cold).
>
> The compiler can then order the code in branches, such as if statements, to favour branches that call these hot functions and disfavour functions cold functions, under the assumption that it is more likely that that the branch that will be taken will call a hot function and less likely to call a cold one.
>
> In addition, the compiler can choose to group together functions marked as hot in a special section in the generated binary, on the premise that since data and instruction caches work based on locality, or the relative distance of related code and data, putting all the often called function together will result in better caching of their code for the entire application.
>
> Good candidates for the hot attribute are core functions which are called very often in your code base. Good candidates for the cold attribute are internal error handling functions which are called only in case of errors.

So, according to these sources, `__attribute__ ((hot))` means:

- optimize calls to this function
- optimize the body of this function
- put body of this function to `.hot` section (to group all hot code in one location)

After source code analysis we can say that "hot" attribute is checked with `(lookup_attribute ("hot", DECL_ATTRIBUTES (current_function_decl))`; and when it is true, the functions's `node->frequency` is set to  `NODE_FREQUENCY_HOT` ([predict.c, compute_function_frequency()](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gcc/gcc/predict.c#2786)).

If the function has frequency as `NODE_FREQUENCY_HOT`,

- If there is no profile information and no `likely/unlikely` on branches, [`maybe_hot_frequency_p`](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gcc/gcc/predict.c#111)  will return true for the function (== "...frequency FREQ is considered to be hot."). This turns value of [`maybe_hot_bb_p`](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gcc/gcc/predict.c#157) into true for all Basic Blocks (BB) in the function ("BB can be CPU intensive and should be optimized for maximal performance.") and [`maybe_hot_edge_p`](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gcc/gcc/predict.c#200) true for all edges in function. In turn in non `-Os`-modes these BB and edges and also loops will be optimized for speed, not for size.
- For all outbound call edges from this function, [`cgraph_maybe_hot_edge_p`](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gcc/gcc/predict.c#168) will return true ("Return true if the call can be hot."). This flag is used in IPA (ipa-inline.c, ipa-cp.c, ipa-inline-analysis.c) and influence inline and cloning decisions

Comment: Don't think so. It is incomplete, and some experiments are needed. I think, hot may also affect code, called from hot function.

Comment: you can expect gcc now or in the future to propagate the hotness of a function to its ancestor and descendent branches and the functions they call where gcc can determine the call graph.

Comment: @codeshot If this is done blindly to all ancestors and descendants then most of the time the whole program would get marked as hot, no? Also in the scenario where a function has multiple ancestors and only one is frequently used this would be a waste.

Comment: It depends on your definition of blind, but good point about the multiple ancestors. I hereby suspend my expectation pending further knowledge

Comment: I thought about this, and yes, if "done blindly" means "without considering branches" it would be an absurd thing to do. But I would definitely expect the gcc implementers, now or in the future, to propagate hotness at least as far as the nearest branch. If a branch is annotated "likely" then I'd expect them to propagate hotness through the branch - both downwards and upwards because likely indicates an extreme probability that takes around 7 or so branches before hotness is diluted much.