# Why would gcc change the order of functions in a binary?

Tags: c, gcc, ld

- Many questions about **forcing the order of functions in a binary** to match the order of the source file
- For example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614209/how-can-i-force-the-order-of-functions-in-a-binary-with-the-gcc-toolchain), [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32013677/gcc-c-keeping-functions-in-order-in-the-binary-file) and others
- I can't understand **why would gcc want to change their order** in the first place?
- What could be gained from that?
- Moreover, why is `toplevel-reorder` default value is true?

Comment: Why do you care about the order of functions in your binary? This should be explained in your question

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch educational purpose, understand the internals better

Answer (score 5):

GCC can change the order of functions, because the C standard (e.g. [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or newer) allows to do that.

There is no obligation for GCC to compile a C function into a single function in the sense of the ELF format. See [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) on Linux

In practice (with optimizations enabled: try compiling `foo.c` with  `gcc -Wall -fverbose-asm -O3 foo.c` then look into the emitted `foo.s` assembler file), the GCC compiler is building intermediate representations like [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html). A big lot of optimizations are transforming GIMPLE to better GIMPLE.

Once the GIMPLE representation is "good enough", the compiler is transforming it to [RTL](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/RTL.html#RTL)

On Linux systems, you could use [dladdr(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html) to find the nearest ELF function to a given address. You can also use [backtrace(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html) to inspect your [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) at runtime.

GCC can even remove functions entirely, in particular `static` functions whose calls would be inline expanded (even *without* any `inline` keyword).

I tend to believe that if you compile and link your entire program with `gcc -O3 -flto -fwhole-program` some non static but unused functions can be removed too....

And you can always write your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to change the order of functions.

If you want to guess how GCC works: download and study its source code (since it is free software) and compile it on your machine, [invoke](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) it with GCC [developer options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html), ask questions on [GCC mailing lists](https://gcc.gnu.org/lists.html)...

See also the [bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) static source code analyzer (some work in progress which could interest you), and the [DECODER](https://www.decoder-project.eu/) project. You can contact me by email about both. You could also contribute to [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) and use it to *generate* GCC plugins (in C++ form).

Answer (score 2):

> What could be gained from that?

Optimization.  If the compiler thinks some code is like to be used a lot it may put that code in a different region than code which is not expected to execute often (or is an error path, where performance is not as important).  And code which is likely to execute after or temporally near some other code should be placed nearby, so it is more likely to be in cache when needed.

[`__attribute__((hot))` and `__attribute__((cold))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028990/semantics-of-gcc-hot-attribute) exist for some of the same reasons.

> why is toplevel-reorder default value is true?

Because 99% of developers are not bothered by this default, and it makes programs faster.  The 1% of developers who need to care about ordering use the attributes, profile-guided optimization or other features which are likely to conflict with `no-toplevel-reorder` anyway.

Comment: Just to make sure I understood: re-ordering of binary code is associated with "breaking" the concept of C functions translated independently, and "orthogonally" from other functions

Comment: @OrenIshShalom: I don't understand what you're asking now.

Comment: No it's not breaking with any concept because there isn't any. One shall not rely on the order of functions in memory.

Comment: sorry, rephrased: If some "hot" code from `foo` is moved to its own section, and `foo` appears **before** `bar` in the source file, then the "hot-foo" part can be **after** `bar`

Comment: @OrenIshShalom: Yes, because there are no guarantees about ordering by default.