# Optimize mathematical operations in c

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization

I am registered in a web programming c where several algorithmic exercises.
I made a very simple problem is as follows:
I receive 4 numbers that determine coordinates of 2 corner of a rectangle and have to calculate the area.
There is a set of tests and when the second corner is below or to the left of the first (x1> x2 || y1> y2) the program exits.
[image]

Exemple:

Input:

```
1 1 4 3
0 0 1 1
9 7 3 6 //Exit
```

Output:

```
6
1
```

This is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    while(1) {
        int x1, x2, y1, y2;
        scanf("%d %d %d %d", &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2);//x1 y1 == A, x2 y2 == B
        if(x1 > x2 || y1 > y2)
            return 0;
        printf("%d\n", (x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1));
    }
}
```

My question is simply a curiosity. I solved the problem with a time of "0052", and there are 3 people in front of me that have managed to solve in "0048" and "0024"!.
What optimicazion methods can I use to get lower time? Probably pointers?

Comment: `scanf` and `printf` (with a flush each time) are going to be much (*much*) slower than anything else.

Comment: Timing a function that waits for keyboard input is a nonsense. You are timing the typist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some thoughts:

1. You could use gcc's `__builtin_expect()` functions to make sure that the conditional is assumed to be false.
2. It's very unlikely that pointers would help you improve your solution.
3. `scanf()` is probably the really slow part. Rewriting this with a parser that only expected decimal integers would probably be much faster. Currently, `scanf()` needs to parse the format string, and the input number could be octal, hexadecimal, or decimal. Or could be invalid input. etc.

Comment: How should i use __builtin_expect() in my program? I never used it and i dont know how apply it.

Comment: @Raxkin: I normally use them through the helper macros `likely(x)` and `unlikely(x)`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109710/likely-unlikely-macros-in-the-linux-kernel

Comment: This question is a whole nonsense. It's timing the standard I/O statements, on which the programmer has no control. (The time for the other statements - hem two elementary C expressions, nothing to optimize - is ridiculously small in comparison.)

Answer (score 0):

Not much, but maybe try declaring `int x1, x2, y1, y2;` before entering the loop.

Comment: I try it, but when i do it, i get a time of 006 that is more than my best time

Comment: You might find that the machine code generated is identical. Having a look at the machine code (especially with the compiler trying to optimise) does no harm beyond that caused by worrying about four digit time numbers without unit. (Opinion: never bother with timings below five seconds, even in microbenchmarks. Do benchmarks with a limit on time rather than loop count.)

Answer (score 0):

Here are my suggestions:

1. in the compile statement use:

   ```
   gcc -O3
   ```
2. place all working variables in global space rather than stack space

   ```
   int x1, x2, y1, y2;, area
   char buffer[100];
   int main()
   {
       do 
       {
           fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin );
           sprintf( buffer, "%d %d %d %d", &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2);
           x2-=x1;
           y2-=y1;
           area = y2*x2;
           printf("%d\n",area); // or perhaps puts( itoa(area) );
       } while(( 0 <= x2) && (0 <= y2)
       return(0);
   }
   ```

Comment: This is an online contest, you don't compile your own code and submit the binary

Comment: what is that supposed to me, I did not submit any binary

Comment: You are suggesting that OP uses compiler optimization flags. Which is why I said that you don't compile your code before submitting. The online judge does the compiling and testing, you just write the code

Comment: There was nothing in the OPs question about any restriction on how the code is compiled