# likely()/unlikely() macros in the Linux kernel with a segmentation fault

Tags: c, gcc, x86, branch-prediction, likely-unlikely

I have an understanding of how the likely()/unlikely() macros work and I also have an understanding of branch prediction. Unfortunately, I did not learn branch prediction in the context of high level programming.

What I want to know is if the evaluation within the likely/unlikely macro results in a segmentation fault, how does that impact the branch prediction history or even the current outcome/pipeline.

I fail to understand that if the validation of the prediction didn't complete, how do we know if it was a success or a failure ?

Comment: I think the start of the this question distracts from what you're really asking, because you want to know how branch prediction works in the case that a speculatively executed branch gets flushed, right?

Comment: Not really. The decision to whether or not to flush the would depend on the evaluation, isn't that correct ? My question was what if the evaluation couldn't be completed. What is the state of the system in that case ?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. If the entire branch has the be flushed, not just code after it. It's not at all related to likely/unlikely, and not even really to exceptions either (you could just corrupt the predictors, an exception is so expensive that taking a hit to bp accuracy doesn't matter) - when this really matters is when you're speculating past several branches and you mispredict the first one. There are several solutions for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`__builtin_expect`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) (used in [the definition of the likely/unlikely macros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18589638/224132)) doesn't generate actual code to evaluate either of its arguments.  All it does is tell the compiler what result to expect *if* it were evaluated.

It might confuse the optimizer if you tell it that `*(int*)NULL` is usually `13`, but (barring compiler bugs) it won't segfault the compiler, or produce code which segfaults at run-time.

[Another answer on the old question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31133787/224132) has actual asm with/without the macro, showing that their effect is in how gcc lays out the code (e.g. putting the unlikely case off by itself, and the likely case in the fall-through not-taken side of a conditional branch where instruction-cache misses are less likely).

---

This isn't quite a duplicate of [likely()/unlikely() macros in the Linux kernel - how do they work? What's their benefit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109710/likely-unlikely-macros-in-the-linux-kernel-how-do-they-work-whats-their), but you will find much more info about how these macros work and what their effect is on that Q&A.