# return likely(x) in c how it is work?

Tags: c

Someone could tell me if this code:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 0;
if (likely(a >= b))
    return 1;
```

make the same this other?

```
return (likely(a>= b))
```

thank so much for the help.

Comment: for a definition of `likely`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109710/likely-unlikely-macros-in-the-linux-kernel-how-do-they-work-whats-their

Comment: Very likely the same. But you must treat the returned value as boolean.

Comment: Well, it depends on what happens when not `a >= b`...

Comment: @WeatherVane, he doesn't need to treat the returned value as boolean, as `likely()` only returns two possible values (`1` and `0`), and as such the return value will be included in the premise `return 1;`.  The code is not exactly the same, as in case `likely()` returns `0`, the code continues past the `return` statement, and no more info has been provided.  So the two statements are not equivalent.

Comment: @LuisColorado we don't know what `likely()` returns, it is not shown.

Comment: @WeatherVane, look for the `__builtin_expect(x, y)` definition in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html and see how it returns the value of its first argument.

Comment: @LuisColorado your link does not contain any function named `likely`. In any case the first paragraph says *we do not recommend general use of these functions*.

Comment: @WheatherVane, you are right... it contains the definition of `__builtin_expect(x, y)` as it is what expands the `likely()` macro definition in the link posted in one of the first comments.  Take the time to read there and come back to the link I posted for the complete thing.

Comment: @LuisColorado this question is not tagged Linux. My comment, similar to others, was the difference between `likely` returning an `int` value which might not be either `0` or `1`. Although I did explore Linux, I have no interest, at the moment in Linux, no matter how many people think that Linux extensions are good, and Windows extensions are bad. I don't care if your car is "better" than mine.

Comment: @WeatherVane, Have I mentioned Linux anyway? where?  It's not tagged `gcc` and the definition of `__builting_expect(x, y)` is gcc specific.  The question talks about the `likely()` function, and one comment provides the definition... What is the reason of your flame? are you disgusted somewhat with my comments?

Comment: @LuisColorado sorry if that was my slip. I was getting annoyed for being taking to task, when from the first few comments at the top, it is plain that I said they are the same only if the return value from the unknown `likely` function is boolean. If there is some arcane definition known only to those who use a particular compiler then mybad. My flame was because I am fed up with those (not you) who pull the "my car is better than yours" routine, "my bolt-ons are good, yours are bad". We use the tools we use, for the reasons we do.

Comment: @WeatherVane, this was also my first touch with the `likely()` function, there's no reason to not follow the link and try to help, even in case you are not familiar with it.  That's actually my case.

Comment: @LuisColorado thank you, your link (which does not mention `likely`) now makes sense in the context of the earlier [link from DaBler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109710/likely-unlikely-macros-in-the-linux-kernel-how-do-they-work-whats-their)

Answer (score 3):

`likely` is not part of the C language.  It must be defined somehow by the context of the code where you saw this.  (It is *probably* a macro that expands to a compiler-specific construct that tells the compiler that `a >= b` is *likely* to be true, which can help optimization.  But from the code you showed, we do not know that for sure.)

Assuming that `likely` is indeed such a macro, we can remove it and proceed to your actual question:

```
if (a >= b)
    return 1;
```

is **not** the same as

```
return a >= b;
```

because they do different things when a is less than b.  `return a >= b;` returns zero when a is less than b, but `if (a >= b) return 1;` goes on to whatever is below the if-statement when a is less than b.

Two constructs that *are* equivalent to `return a >= b;` are

```
if (a >= b)
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
```

and

```
if (a >= b)
    return 1;
return 0;
```

Most experienced C programmers would rather see `return a >= b;` than either.

[Addendum: `return likely(a >= b);` is a peculiar thing to write, because the function is going to return either way, and the code setting up the return value is short, simple, and (often) branch-free.  It could conceivably provide a hint to [interprocedural optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization), but it would be more natural to express that kind of hint as an annotation on the function prototype, e.g.

```
extern int fstat(int fd, struct stat *st)
    __attribute__((expected_return_value(0)));
```

(Note: not a real GCC function annotation as far as I know.)]

Answer (score 2):

They're not the same, because the first block of code doesn't return immediately when `a >= b` is false, it continues on with the rest of the function (which you haven't shown). So unless the next line is `return 0;`, they're different.

With the values of `a` and `b` that you give, the whole block of code is simply equivalent to `return 1;`. But I assume that it's possible for `a` and `b` to have different values.

Comment: In the all code there are a else with return 0, so if that case are the same? int a = 1;
int b = 0;
if (likely(a >= b))
    return 1; 
else return 0

Comment: Then it's the same. If that's what you meant you should have written it in the question.

Comment: @annacoobs, `if (likely(a>=b)) return 1; else return 0;` is indeed equivalent, but as you say, "In the all code there are an else..." cannot be made equivalent, because there can be some *lateral effects* in the *all code* that make them different.  They are only equivalent if the *all code* reduces to a "return 0;" after the `if` statement.