# What optimizations does __builtin_unreachable facilitate?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization

Judging from gcc's documentation

> If control flow reaches the point of the `__builtin_unreachable`, the program is undefined.

I thought `__builtin_unreachable` may be used as a hint to the optimizer in all sorts of creative ways. So I did a little experiment

```
void stdswap(int& x, int& y)
{
    std::swap(x, y);
}

void brswap(int& x, int& y)
{
    if(&x == &y)
        __builtin_unreachable();
    x ^= y;
    y ^= x;
    x ^= y;
}

void rswap(int& __restrict x, int& __restrict y)
{
    x ^= y;
    y ^= x;
    x ^= y;
}
```

[gets compiled to](https://godbolt.org/z/cphR1Q) (g++ -O2)

```
stdswap(int&, int&):
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rsi]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], edx
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], eax
        ret
brswap(int&, int&):
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        xor     eax, DWORD PTR [rsi]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], eax
        xor     eax, DWORD PTR [rsi]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], eax
        xor     DWORD PTR [rdi], eax
        ret
rswap(int&, int&):
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsi]
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], eax
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], edx
        ret
```

I assume that `stdswap` and `rswap` is optimal from the optimizer's perspective. Why doesn't `brswap` get compiled to the same thing? Can I get it to compile to the same thing with `__builtin_unreachable`?

Comment: The assembly for `stdswap` and `rswap` actually works fine even if `x` and `y` alias. GCC will also happily emit the same instruction sequence as these functions if one does the swap normally using a local variable i.e. `int temp = y; y = x; x = temp;` – nowadays, "XOR swap" is an anti-pattern most of the time.

Comment: @ArneVogel That's the point, XOR swapping has different behaviour when they alias and therefore the compiler may not emit the same instructions as `stdswap`. I specifically chose a anti-pattern so that the effect of `__builtin_unreachable` can be verified.

Comment: Well, my main point was that correlation does not equal causation. I'd guess that the xor swap optimization from `rswap` is really old – almost as old as the bygone era of scarce registers and rather dumb compilers – and that GCC developers later never particularly cared about improving it. A lot of compiler optimizations are basically special cases on top of heuristics, both of which someone had to implement, and hopefully demonstrate a benefit in a handful of reference applications somehow considered meaningful.

Comment: I believe your second function not optimizing the way it should is just missed optimization on gcc's part rather than incorrect use of __builtin_unreachable. In other contexts (e.g., attaching value ranges to a variable) it works just fine. Gcc has quite a few missed optimizations.  (Restrict placed in function bodies rather than on function arguments doesn't optimize as well as it could either.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74590831/using-restrict-to-express-possible-partial-overlap))

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The purpose of `__builtin_unreachable` is to help the compiler to:

- Remove dead code  (that programmer knows will never be executed)
- Linearize the code by letting compiler know that the path is "cold" (similar effect is achieved by calling `noreturn` function)

Consider the following:

```
void exit_if_true(bool x);

int foo1(bool x)
{
    if (x) {
        exit_if_true(true);
        //__builtin_unreachable(); // we do not enable it here
    } else {
        std::puts("reachable");
    }

    return 0;
}
int foo2(bool x)
{
    if (x) {
        exit_if_true(true);
        __builtin_unreachable();  // now compiler knows exit_if_true
                                  // will not return as we are passing true to it
    } else {
        std::puts("reachable");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Generated code:

```
foo1(bool):
        sub     rsp, 8
        test    dil, dil
        je      .L2              ; that jump is going to change
        mov     edi, 1
        call    exit_if_true(bool)
        xor     eax, eax         ; that tail is going to be removed
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
.L2:
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    puts
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
foo2(bool):
        sub     rsp, 8
        test    dil, dil
        jne     .L9              ; changed jump
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    puts
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
.L9:
        mov     edi, 1
        call    exit_if_true(bool)
```

Notice the differences:

- `xor eax, eax` and `ret` were removed as now compiler knows that is a dead code.
- The compiler swapped the order of branches: branch with `puts` call now comes first so that conditional jump can be faster (forward branches that are not taken are faster both when predicted and when there is no prediction information).

The assumption here is that branch that ends with `noreturn` function call or `__builtin_unreachable` will either be executed only once or leads to `longjmp` call or exception throw both of which are rare and do not need to be prioritized during optimization.

You are trying to use it for a different purpose - by giving compiler information about aliasing (and you can try doing the same for alignment). Unfortunately GCC doesn't understand such address checks.

As you have noticed, adding `__restrict__` helps. So `__restrict__` works for aliasing, `__builtin_unreachable` does not.

Look at the following example that uses `__builtin_assume_aligned`:

```
void copy1(int *__restrict__ dst, const int *__restrict__ src)
{
    if (reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(dst) % 16 == 0) __builtin_unreachable();
    if (reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(src) % 16 == 0) __builtin_unreachable();
        
    dst[0] = src[0];
    dst[1] = src[1];
    dst[2] = src[2];
    dst[3] = src[3];
}

void copy2(int *__restrict__ dst, const int *__restrict__ src)
{
    dst = static_cast<int *>(__builtin_assume_aligned(dst, 16));
    src = static_cast<const int *>(__builtin_assume_aligned(src, 16));

    dst[0] = src[0];
    dst[1] = src[1];
    dst[2] = src[2];
    dst[3] = src[3];
}
```

Generated code:

```
copy1(int*, int const*):
        movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rsi]
        movups  XMMWORD PTR [rdi], xmm0
        ret
copy2(int*, int const*):
        movdqa  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rsi]
        movaps  XMMWORD PTR [rdi], xmm0
        ret
```

You could assume that compiler can understand that `dst % 16 == 0` means the pointer is 16-byte aligned, but it doesn't. So unaligned stores and loads are used, while the second version generates faster instructions that require address to be aligned.

Comment: Unreachable is more than just cold.  "Cold" means executed rarely, especially just at startup or cleanup.  You tell GCC about that with `__builtin_expect` on branch conditions ([likely / unlikely macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109710/how-do-the-likely-unlikely-macros-in-the-linux-kernel-work-and-what-is-their-ben/31133787#31133787)), or [`__attribute__((cold))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) on a function, or Profile-Guided Optimization (PGO).  Other than that terminology nitpick, nice answer.

Comment: The correct term instead of "cold" for this case is "dead" (which you used elsewhere but is not a synonym).

Comment: No, it is "cold" as executed rarely. Basic block that ends with unrechable statement is considered to be unlikely executed, as if when __builtin_expect was used. The code past unrechable statement is "dead" and is removed. The code example demonstrates how basic block order gets reversed based on assumed probabilities of branches by code generator.

Comment: The effect unreachable statement has on branch probability is similar to calling `noreturn` function or calling `__attribute__((cold))` function. The assumption is that such branch cannot be executed more than once in program lifetime as this is "cold" (although `longjmp` and exceptions break this rule).  In C unreachable usually means that code path leads to `exit` or `abort` call.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are the trying to micro-optimize your code wrong moving a wrong direction.

__builtin_unreachable as well as __builtin_expect doing what expected - in your case remove unnecessary `cmp` and `jnz` from unused if operator.

Compiler should generate the machine code using C code you've write to produce predictable program. And during optimization, it able to find and optimize  (i.e. replace with better machine code version) some patterns, when it known to optimization algorithm - such optimization would not broke the program behavior.

E.g. something like

```
char a[100];
for(int i=0; i < 100; i++)
   a[i]  = 0;
```

will be replaced single call to library std::memset(a,0,100) which is implemented using assembly, and optimal for the current CPU architecture.

As well as compiler able to detect

```
x ^= y;
y ^= x;
x ^= y;
```

and replace it with simplest mashie code.

I think your if operator and unreached  directive influenced the compiler optimizer, so that is can not optimize.

In case of swapping of two integers, 3-rd temporary exchange variable can be removed by compiler it self, i.e. it is going to be something like

```
movl    $2, %ebx
movl    $1, %eax
xchg    %eax,%ebx
```

Where ebx and eax register values are actually your x and y. You can implement it your self like

```
void swap_x86(int& x, int& y)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__( "xchg %%rax, %%rbx": "=a"(x), "=b"(y) : "a"(x), "b"(y) : );
}
...
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
swap_x86(a,b);
```

When to use __builtin_unreachable? Probably when you known that some situation are practically impossible, but logically it may happens. I.e. you have some function like

```
void foo(int v) {

    switch( v ) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        default:
            __builtin_unreachable();
    }
}
```

And you know that `v` argument value is always between 0 and 3. However, int range is `-2147483648` to `2147483647` (when int is 32 bit type), compiler have no idea about real values range and not able to remove the default block (as well as some cmp instructions etc), but it will warn you if you don't add this block into switch. So in this case `__builtin_unreachable` may help.

Comment: *"Probably when you known that some situation are practically impossible, but logically it may happens."* Be very very careful about using __builtin_unreachable(); in default: case labels. I spent days trying to figure out random branches into .rodata areas.
In my case, there were 0 through 25 case labels and a default: case, for an enum from 0 to 128. And a switch value of 71 that caused the problem.
6.3.0 had range checking code but 8.3.0 optimized it away.