# Best way to deal with namespace collision of likely/unlikely macros, with boost code

Tags: c++, boost

The class `boost::date_time::special_values_parser` has a method named `likely`. However, I am using this class in code that uses `likely`/`unlikely` as branch-prediction macros (see [How do the likely/unlikely macros in the Linux kernel work and what is their benefit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109710/how-do-the-likely-unlikely-macros-in-the-linux-kernel-work-and-what-is-their-ben)). Is there a way to still use this code while also using the macros?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to still use this code while also using the macros?

Yes. Function-like macros require `()` immediately to expand, regular functions don't. Workaround:

```
(boost::date_time::special_values_parser::likely)( /* ... */ );
```

Comment: That's a good way to call it, but unfortunately, just including the header file for `boost::date_time::special_values_parser` conflicts with the macro.

Comment: @jhourback include the headers *before* defining macros.

Comment: That could work, but it's tricky because the header is included by other headers, so I would have to mandate a specific order of header inclusion in other headers. (i.e., include the header that defines `likely` only after you include the header that includes `boost::date_time::special_values_parser`).

Comment: @jhourback defining lower case macros with no prefix is the decision that led you to a name conflict, and this solution tries to mitigate that. The actual solution is to give the macros ugly names like `MY_LIB_LIKELY`.