# What is the purpose of C++20's [[likely]] or [[unlikely]] attribute

Tags: c++, c++20

I have been reading more on C++ 20, and recently noticed the `[[likely]]` or `[[unlikely]]` attributes. Which seems like an interesting concept, not found in previous versions of C++. According to the official CPP Reference:

> Allow the compiler to optimize for the case where paths of execution including that statement are more or less likely than any alternative path of execution that does not include such a statement.

What does this really imply?

This blog post, argues against using them because it seems more like pre-mature form of optimization and a few other details. https://blog.aaronballman.com/2020/08/dont-use-the-likely-or-unlikely-attributes/

Comment: One example is that if you call a function inside of an `[[unlikely]]` branch, even if the function is small it might not be inlined, since inlining it would increase the function's size with code that is unlikely to be reached

Comment: Looks like another question has answers to this one: [How do the likely/unlikely macros in the Linux kernel work and what is their benefit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/109710)

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues, seems very odd. Kind of a waste, but, also by the same token, it seems to give the programmer the freedom of control in terms of instructing the compiler for certain level of optimization. This is my understanding based on your explanation here.

Comment: @mouviciel, not the same question mate. Please, this is not a duplicate. I googled for hours and days, I even seen that link before. Thanks.

Comment: @AbigailJohnsson - I didn't say that the questions are the same. I just thought that the accepted answer there may be valuable in the context of this one.

Comment: ‘triggering discussion’ is not really what this site is for. In fact, there’s a whole process for closing questions that only ask for people’s opinions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's meant to let the compiler know which path is the "fast path", as in "more likely to happen".

For example, imagine implementing `vector::at`. This function throws if the index is out of bounds. But you expect this situation to happen very rarely, most of the time you expect the users to access a valid element. You can mark the throwing path `[[unlikely]]` and the compiler will understand your intention and might optimize the program accordingly.

Comment: **Ayxan**, thanks for your answer. You example seems bad, why not use the keyword `noexcept` ?

Comment: @AbigailJohnsson `noexcept` means this function will not throw. But `vector::at` will and should throw if the index is out of bounds.

Comment: **Ayxan**, I know. But, based out of your example here.

Comment: @AbigailJohnsson `unlikely` ≠ `never`

Comment: @AbigailJohnsson I am not sure what part of my answer is confusing you, but here is some sample code: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fdxc89Exx

Comment: @Sebastian, exactly. So, does not seem reasonable use case then.

Comment: It's exactly the use case. It is unlikely to throw, but can.

Comment: Another potential example: logging code which you don't expect to be enabled most of the time, so you might want to give a hint to the compiler to keep it out of the main flow of the function.

Comment: @DanielSchepler logging in C++ is typically done with macros that disappear on release mode, so not the best example perhaps?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili, I don't know what sort of logging your servers do, but mine can be configured at runtime to log any level of detail from "only critical failures leading to immediate shutdown" to "entry and exit of each function, including function parameters".

Comment: yeh, but what does this mean in terms of the generated machine code? what's the difference to simply leaving it out?

Comment: @memoryofadream See the example here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/likely#Example