# In c++ what is the importance in terms of performance of using 'else' in situations where it doesn't change the flow of the program?

Tags: c++, if-statement, optimization, micro-optimization, branch-prediction

There are cases where (logically at least) it makes no difference if I leave out the `else` keyword, for example:

```
int func(int num)
{
    if(num == 10) return 99999;
    **else** return -1;
}
```

Question is, does the presence of `else` make any difference performance-wise in less trivial cases than this? I know of the existence of the branch predictor and the pipeline, is it affected by the absence/presence of `else`? Maybe it doesn't even matter since compilers might just optmize it away anyways, but I'm curious.

*I've been spending my time on sites that let you practice solving problems, almost all of the problems have trivial cases, for example when making an `isPrime()` function you might wanna filter out <=1 numbers first and *only then* jump to the business logic. That's where the curiosity came from.*

Comment: Look at the generated assembly.  *Probably*, the code generated will be **identical**.  I omit the `else` for that final case, but that's just my personal convention.  As far as the language is concerned, it's six of one, half-dozen of the other.

Comment: There is no `else` instruction on the processor. If you're actually worried there will somehow be a performance difference, you have to try it and measure. Realistically you have to talk about a specific piece of code, not arbitrary "less trivial" cases.

Comment: Also if you're worried about performance you can give a hint that you if is unlikely to be true : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/likely... but the only real proof is still to measure (profile) your code and fix the real bottlenecks.

Comment: About the sites that let you solve practical problem, you don't mean competitive coding right. Because don't bother looking for a few nanoseconds here and there... that's way below their measurement accuracy (tens of milliseconds at least). The real goal there is just to get the complexit (big O) right. Oh and it seems to pickup real bad coding practices too

Comment: It's not about performance, but about readability. Using an if-else with two returns makes it clear *to the reader* that there are exactly two options. Otherwise you could have several separate if's with returns for various conditions, and then `return -1`for "the rest".

Comment: If you ever try to generalize a given `if` to an `if constexpr` (admittedly very rare) it does make a difference for compilation, the `else` version is more general in this sense.

Answer (score 2):

#### TL:DR: This probably makes no difference, and no easily-predictable difference

**CPUs run machine code, not C++ source.**  In machine code we only have "goto" (jumps) and `if()goto` conditional branches. This `else` doesn't make a difference to the actual program logic and thus you'd expect either version would compile to the same machine code. (And if it doesn't, the worse one is a missed-optimization compiler defect.)

But source-code structure (such as hiding something behind an `else` vs. on the main path after an `if`) might or might not affect the compiler's heuristics for guessing which path is more often taken and thus laying out that as the fast path with fewer taken branches, in the absence of `[[likely]]` / `[[unlikely]]` decorators or profile-guided optimization info.    Compilers have various heuristics for guessing whether to optimize for the case where an `if` is normally taken or normally not taken, e.g. looking at the condition and whether it's comparing a variable to a small or large number, especially if it has any value-range info on the variable being compared.

See [Ciro's answer showing the effect on branch layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31133787).  Note that this is unrelated to runtime branch *prediction* except on older CPUs where static prediction (forward-taken / backwards not-taken) is sometimes used when dynamic predictors are cold.  With IT-TAGE predictors (at least in Intel since Haswell), that doesn't happen, they always predict something.  Taken branches in machine code are a bit less efficient than fall-through (e.g. into an `if` body) because the front-end isn't just fetching contiguous code.

**But there's no direct or simple connection between source layout and machine-code layout**; it's the compiler's job optimize branch layout, not just transliterate C into asm, so you're going to have to look at the asm (e.g. on https://godbolt.org/) if you want to know what the compiler did.  See also [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output)

If you're interested in micro-optimizations, see [What considerations go into predicting latency for operations on modern superscalar processors and how can I calculate them by hand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51607391/what-considerations-go-into-predicting-latency-for-operations-on-modern-supersca) and read up on details of recent CPUs, like Chips & Cheese's write-up of Zen 4.
https://chipsandcheese.com/2022/11/05/amds-zen-4-part-1-frontend-and-execution-engine/  And older articles like David Kanter's excellent deep dives into [Sandybridge](https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/) and [Haswell](https://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/).  Also links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info such as Agner Fog's excellent microarchitecture guides: https://www.agner.org/optimize/

For basics, see [Modern Microprocessors
A 90-Minute Guide!](https://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/)