# Explicit Branch-prediction in JVM-based langauges?

Tags: jvm, jvm-bytecode

Is there any way for JVM-based languages to indicate to the interpreter that a branch is `cold` or `unlikely` etc.?

Specifically I mean some kind of branch attribute like the Linux Kernel's `unlikely()` and `likely()` macros.

How could one indicate this in an assembler (like Krakatau or Jasmin)? Or any JVM-based language, like Scala or Java?

Comment: There is no need for that. Unlike statically compiled languages, JVM automatically determines which branch is hot at runtime and JIT-compiles the code accordingly.

Comment: @apangin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109710/how-do-the-likely-unlikely-macros-in-the-linux-kernel-work-and-what-is-their-ben According to this post, `unlilkely` and `likely` only help on the first pass of the branch anyway. Isn't this just as useful in a JIT-compiled language, then?

If the answer is "The JVM does not have that feature", feel free to answer that and I will accept!

Comment: The first passes are executed in the interpreter, which is rather slow comparing to JIT-compiled code. Hinting branches will not make performance difference for the interpreter.

Comment: If you assume the simplest interpreter, conditional forward branches should be unlikely, so arrange the code that the likely branch is the one not jumping. But as said by apangin, there is no relevance for the commonly used JVMs today.